# Pass variable from LaTeX to bibtex (for easy anonymization)?

Tags: bibtex, environment-variables

I typically use a variable for my name in `.bib` bibliography entries, for instance:

```
@String {myname = "Prof. Dr. Hortensia Audactor"}
String {myname = "Anonymized" }

@article{audactor2005pflanzen,
  title = {Wie Pflanzen hören... die Geheimnisse der Sonobotanik},
  author = myname,
  journal = {Draft: \url{http://www.inventionen.de/vortrag_audactor.html}},
  year = {2005}
}
```

... since some article submissions require anonymization. Then, in principle, I can just change the at sign `@` in front of the `String` command, to determine which one is active; so if I want to anonymize, I'd simply make sure that instead of the above, I have something like:

```
String {myname = "Prof. Dr. Hortensia Audactor"}
@String {myname = "Anonymized" }
```

However, now I've ran into a problem, where I have to work on two articles, both fed from the same bibtex file and referring to the same citation -- in the one, anonymization is required; in the other, it isn't. Which means, in essence, that now I have to maintain two `.bib` files -- one with anonymized name, other without -- if I don't want to manually change the `@` sign each time I compile the one or the other article ... and of course, I find either of these approaches to be a pain.

Ideally, what I'd want to do is to pass an option to the `\bibliography` command in the `.tex` file; say the article which requires anonymization would "pass a variable" to bibtex in the LaTeX code, as in:

```
\bibliography[anon=yes]{mybibliography}
```

... and then, there would be some code in the `.bib` file, which if it encounters `anon=yes`, would set the `@String {myname` to "Anonymized" -- otherwise, the actual name would remain (which would be the case for the article with no anonymization requirements, which would call `\bibliography` without any arguments).

So, any ideas if what I want to do is possible? (*In section "19 Some practical tricks" of [Tame the BeaST](http://www.lsv.ens-cachan.fr/~markey/BibTeX/doc/ttb_en.pdf) there are some functions using `if$`, which makes me think what I'd want to do is possible -- unfortunately, I cannot as of yet determine whether that is the case; EDIT: that section is for `.bst` files, so it's not applicable here; I wouldn't want to mess with `.bst`, only `.bib`*)

Comment: It's not necessary to sign your questions (as there is already a box with your username below it) or to begin them with a greeting.

Comment: Is this a common way to do things in your field? In mine, we just try to avoid obvious self-references such as "In previous work (Smith 2009) we have shown" but otherwise leave references alone.  (Especially since one can easily figure out the reference by looking up the paper in the journal using the rest of the citation information.)

Comment: @Thorten - sorry about that, bad habit from email (_I often hate it when people can't be bothered to write lead in/lead out_); @Alan Munn - well, some require that references to author are anonymized ('double blind', I guess), so I'd rather be safe than sorry :) Cheers!

Comment: @Alan I also wondered about this when reading the question. This approach even seems to disclose more information about who the author is (less "blind"!), because one would understand that the author coincides with the "anonymized" author, and if they then look up the published referenced work (perhaps, in order to understand this work better), they will know the author definitely...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can include **multiple bibliography files**.

For instance, you can have two (very short) Bibtex files: `anon.bib` that defines the anonymised version of your macro and `myname.bib` defines it in the usual way. Then you have `mybibliography.bib` with everything else.

Now it is easy to use either

```
\bibliography{anon,mybibliography}
```

or

```
\bibliography{myname,mybibliography}
```

in your Latex source depending on which version you want. No need to edit any *.bib files.

---

A minimal working example.

**x.bib**:

```
@STRING{test = {Xxxx}}
```

**y.bib**:

```
@STRING{test = {Yyyy}}
```

**z.bib**:

```
@MISC{z,
    author = test,
    title = test,
    year = {2000}
}
```

**a.tex**:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}
\cite{z}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{x,z}
\end{document}
```

**b.tex**:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}
\cite{z}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{y,z}
\end{document}
```

The following files are generated by Bibtex.

**a.bbl**:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{1}

\bibitem{z}
Xxxx.
\newblock Xxxx, 2000.

\end{thebibliography}
```

**b.bbl**:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{1}

\bibitem{z}
Yyyy.
\newblock Yyyy, 2000.

\end{thebibliography}
```

---

In general, including multiple Bibtex files is a powerful technique with which you can easily control the behaviour of Bibtex by including the right combination of Bibtex files. [Here is another example of the trick](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4456/how-do-you-cite-conference-proceedings/4460#4460).

Comment: Have you tried this?  It doesn't actually work.  The `@string` command works on a per-bib-file basis.

Comment: @Alan: I actually use a similar trick often: I have files that contain a bunch of `@STRING` definitions (and nothing else), and they are used in another file (that does not define them).

Comment: @Jukka So I wonder why my test of this didn't work.  It was the first thing I thought of but it didn't seem to work for me.

Comment: @Alan: I now tried it with a minimal example; works fine. See the edits. (By the way, it also works perfectly with rubber; you can simply run something like `rubber -Wall a.tex b.tex` and both versions are up-to-date.)

Comment: @Jukka My reference manager makes was adding braces to the name field; editing the raw bibtex makes the solution work.

Comment: @Jukka Suomela - I did try to hint that I find maintaining multiple bibliographies a pain; however, thanks and +1 for the detailed answer!

Comment: @sdaau: Here you are *not* maintaining multiple bibliography files. You have two files that you do not need to edit ever (unless your name changes...). You only need to edit `mybibliography.bib`, and you do not need to duplicate any information.

Comment: @Jukka Suomela - ah, sorry, I misread your answer (I guess `x.bib` and `y.bib` got the better of me :) ) Yeah, it seems as a much more straightforward solution. Cheers!

Comment: @sdaau I don't think you understand Jukka's solution. Your "multiple bibliographies" would just be the following: `anon.bib` = `@STRING {myname = "Anonymized" }` and `non-anon.bib` = `@STRING {myname = "Prof. Dr. Hortensia Audactor"}`.  Your main bibliography remains the same. When you want to anonymize your name, you use `\bibliography{anon,mainbibfile}` This is by far the best solution to your problem.

Comment: @Alan Munn - yes, exactly; sorry about that, I misread @Jukka Suomela's answer; thanks for the clarification - cheers!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to use a macro in the `.bib` file, for example `\myname`, and then define this in the LaTeX file. You would probably want to `\providecommand` the macro in the `@preamble` of the `.bib` file, so that there is not an error if you forget to define it in the LaTeX file.

Comment: Does this really work? Will the macro allow the parts of the name to be used for formatting?  For example, if your bibentry is `name="\ifanon Anonymized\else\Your Name\fi"`, then "Your Name" shows up in the citations/bibliography instead of e.g. "Your Name (2011)" instead of "Name (2011)" etc.  Wouldn't a macro for the name field work the same way?

Comment: @Alan: I guess I'm used to numerical citations, where this never arises!

Comment: (How would that work anyway with 'anonymous'? I'm actually confused by the whole concept: if the names are wrong, the reference is wrong.)

Comment: @Joseph Ok, so I'm not imagining things.  What really is needed is the concept of a conditional within the bib field itself, but not in the form of latex source, instead operating on the field content.

Comment: I agree that it's kind of a weird request, since just anonymizing the name doesn't really seem to achieve much.  Normally when submitting papers for blind review you mainly watch for obvious self-references such as "in previous work (Smith et al. 2009) we have shown..." but otherwise leave in references as they are.

Comment: @Alan: In my area (chemistry), we don't review that way so I would not know. As you say, 'previous work' would always make it clear who the authors are. We only have anonymous reviewers.

Comment: @Joseph when my field (Linguistics) shifted to true blind review (a long time ago now; probably in the 70s) the number of accepted papers by women and junior faculty increased dramatically.  I'm still surprised that other fields don't have it.

Comment: @Joseph Wright - thanks for that, I guess my solution below follows the approach you stated; @Alan Munn - I believe that my example below illustrates that only the name variable would be changed, the rest of the references remain the same...

Comment: @Alan: [Well OT] I can see a few reasons why we don't do blind reviews: For the editorial offices, it would mean more work (currently, they just send out raw authors drafts, which would need to be edited for example in the 'thanks'). Quite often experimental work gives away where people work ('this was run on instrument XXX'). As we are a paper-based subject, there would be a load of refs which pointed up who the authors are. Finally, if you keep up with the area you'll immediate recognise a particular groups work. (You can usually tell who the _reviewers_ are!)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, haven't yet seen the responses, but I think I got it running somewhat...

Here's the example `test.bib` file:

```
------------- NEEDED MACRO
-------------
@preamble{ "\def\ConditionalName#1{\ifx\anonme\undefined#1\else\if\anonme1{Anonymized}\else#1\fi\fi}" }

------------- DEFINITION OF ANONYMIZED VARS/NAMES
-------------
@preamble{ "\def\myname{\ConditionalName{Prof. Dr. Hortensia Audactor}}" }
@String {myname = "\myname"}

------------- BIB ENTRIES
-------------
@article{audactor2005pflanzen,
  title = {Wie Pflanzen hören... die Geheimnisse der Sonobotanik},
  author = myname,
  journal = {Draft: \url{http://www.inventionen.de/vortrag_audactor.html}},
  year = {2005}
}
```

Then, this is `test.tex` - which should show the names as they are (and there's nothing special in it):

```
% test.tex
%
% build with:
% pdflatex test.tex
% bibtex test
% pdflatex test.tex
% pdflatex test.tex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{url}
\begin{document}

\section{Content}

Blah, blah, blah \cite{audactor2005pflanzen}; blah blah.

\bigskip

% no anonymization here
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{test}

\end{document}
```

... and finally, here is `testanon.tex`:

```
% testanon.tex
%
% build with:
% pdflatex testanon.tex
% bibtex testanon
% pdflatex testanon.tex
% pdflatex testanon.tex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{url}
\begin{document}

\section{Content}

Blah, blah, blah \cite{audactor2005pflanzen}; blah blah.

\bigskip

\def\anonme{1}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{test}

\end{document}
```

... where `\def\anonme{1}` is used as a "signal" that anonymization should be made.

Just for personal reference, here is the .tex file I used for testing:

```
% macrotest.tex
\documentclass{minimal}

\begin{document}

% via \newcommand:
\newcommand\ConditionalName[1]{
\ifx\anonme\undefined%
#1%
\else%
  \if\anonme1%
  {Anonymized}%
  \else%
  #1%
  \fi%
\fi%
}

% via \def, in single line (handles punctuation better)
% \def\ConditionalName#1{\ifx\anonme\undefined#1\else\if\anonme1{Anonymized}\else#1\fi\fi}

Test of \verb!\ConditionalName!: \ConditionalName{John A}, then def (\def\anonme{1}), then again: \ConditionalName{John B}, then def 0 (\def\anonme{0}), then again: \ConditionalName{John C} .. then undef (\makeatletter\let\anonme\@undefined\makeatother), then again: \ConditionalName{John D} .. then def (\def\anonme{1}), then again: \ConditionalName{John E}.

\end{document}
```

Thanks for all the comments, I'll take a look at them now :)
Cheers!