# Underline my name in the bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, formatting, highlighting

For several documents I'm preparing, I need to highlight (or underline) occurences of my name within the bibliography.

Is there an easy way of doing this?

Comment: The title is not consistent with the body of the question: do you want to highlight, or to underline?

Comment: Strongly related, and with more answers, is https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/73136/34551

Answer (score 30):

It depends on how you prepare the bibliography. If you are preparing it with BibTeX, you can use a trick I mentioned earlier today, which requires you change the .bib files; this definition should go in the .tex file

```
\newcommand{\myname}[1]{\textit{Wurm, Y.}}
```

and an entry in the .bib file will have

```
author={{\myname{wurm}} and Zauthor, X.}
```

However this depends also on how you want the names displayed in the bibliography.

If you don't want to act on the bib files, a different approach might work:

```
\usepackage{xstring}

\let\originalbibitem\bibitem
\def\bibitem#1#2\par{%
  \noexpandarg
  \originalbibitem{#1}
  \StrSubstitute{#2}{Wurm}{\textit{Wurm}}\par}
```

This exploits the fact that BibTeX separates each `\bibitem` entry with empty lines. A different redefinition of `\bibitem` must be done if you use the abbrv bibstyle instead of plain.

For biblatex the situation is more involved; I got something with

```
\usepackage{xstring}
\noexpandarg\exploregroups
\makeatletter
\let\orig@blx@bbl@entry\blx@bbl@entry
\def\blx@bbl@entry#1\endentry{%
  \StrSubstitute{#1}{Wurm}{\textit{Wurm}}[\Result]%
  \expandafter\orig@blx@bbl@entry\Result\endentry}
\makeatother
```

for the standard style; but I don't know if there are side effects. Probably acting as Alan Munn suggested in a comment is best.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply greg. However, I was hoping to be able to only change something in my .tex file. Messing with .bib file (which may require having multiple copies) is something I would like to avoid...

Comment: @Yannick: see the edit

Comment: Is there a biber/biblatex solution?

Comment: The accepted answer to this question: [Pass variable from LaTeX to bibtex (for easy anonymization)?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17675/pass-variable-from-latex-to-bibtex-for-easy-anonymization) gives you another way take on the multiple bibfile: you make your name a variable in the bib file and then alias it to a command. So you don't really have multiple bib files, just one line for the special formatting, and the other for not.

Comment: Thanks for all the replies. Problem with having a different bib file with different formatting is that the formatting will be applied in the main text as well, not only in the bibliography. (I want my name to be highlighted only in the list of references)...

Comment: An acceptable workaround is for me to use what @Alan Munn suggests but instead of changing my name's formatting, changing the formatting of the article title. Cheers!

Comment: This is simple and works well, however how could replace two or more last names? (e.g. remplate `Smith` by `\textit{Smith}` and Harrison by `\textit{Harrison}`.

Comment: @alfC You need to add more substitutions of the same kind.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that, putting one `StrSubstitute` after the other or nest and didn't work (didn't replace anything).

Answer (score 12):

If you are using biblatex you can override the formatting of the list of authors:

```
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem} %for \uline

\DeclareNameFormat{author}{%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{YourLastName}}%
    {\uline{\ifblank{#4}{}{#4\space}#1}}%
    {\ifblank{#4}{}{#4\space}#1}%
\ifthenelse{\value{listcount}<\value{liststop}}%
    {\addcomma\space}
    {}}
```

This of course means you have to reproduce formatting of the backend you are using but it allows you to e.g. underline your initials *and* last name together[1]. The example above is fairly basic (for example it doesn't care about inserting "et al." or "and" as required by some guidelines).

[1] I might be wrong here (I couldn't make the attached example to work) but it seems to me that egreg's solution works at `.bbl` file level, where initials, first and last names are still kept separately.

---

(edit)

Below is a redefined default name formatting macro (based on definition of a `name:first-last` macro from a `biblatex.def` file). I'm sorry for my poor coding style. If someone could show me how to properly restructure this macro (to avoid repetition) that would be great.

```
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem} %for \uline

\renewbibmacro*{name:first-last}[4]{%
  \usebibmacro{name:delim}{#2#3#1}%
  \usebibmacro{name:hook}{#2#3#1}%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{YourLastName}}% matches last name against YourLastName
    {
      \uline{% wrapped with \uline
      \ifblank{#2}{}{\mkbibnamefirst{#2}\isdot\bibnamedelimd}%
      \ifblank{#3}{}{%
        \mkbibnameprefix{#3}\isdot%
        \ifpunctmark{'}%
          {}%
          {\ifuseprefix{\bibnamedelimc}{\bibnamedelimd}}}%
      \mkbibnamelast{#1}\isdot%
      \ifblank{#4}{}{\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnameaffix{#4}\isdot}}}%
    {% original
      \ifblank{#2}{}{\mkbibnamefirst{#2}\isdot\bibnamedelimd}%
      \ifblank{#3}{}{%
        \mkbibnameprefix{#3}\isdot%
        \ifpunctmark{'}%
          {}%
          {\ifuseprefix{\bibnamedelimc}{\bibnamedelimd}}}%
      \mkbibnamelast{#1}\isdot%
      \ifblank{#4}{}{\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnameaffix{#4}\isdot}}}
```

Comment: While this is an old post, I have recently noticed that the format in [biblatex](http://ftp.snt.utwente.nl/pub/software/tex/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/RELEASE) (see the release notes for version 3.3). In particular, when using `DeclareNameFormat`, one should add `\nameparts{#1}` at the beginning of its definition and use `\namepartXXXX` instead of the numbered arguments `#2` and so on as detailed in the release notes.

Answer (score 3):

I am using Mendeley to manage my references. It can output a `bibtex` file but LaTeX has problems with lines that are too long (abstracts). I use a simple shell script to strip abstracts in a new `.bib` file, and following **egreg's** advice, included the `{\myname{wurm}}` change to the `.bib` file. I am also using the bibliography style `ieeetr` and my name is underlined as expected.

For me, the shell script contains:

```
sed "/^abstract/d" library.bib | sed "s|Hurvitz, P. M.|{\\\myname{hurvitz}}|" > library_noabstract.bib
```

and in my `.tex` file:

```
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\newcommand{\myname}[1]{\uline{P. M. Hurvitz}}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Using `\newcommand{\myname}[1]{\uline{#1}}` would be the more general option.

Answer (score 3):

I was using the answer by @Andrzej until recently; I think the problem developed when moving from  `TeX Live 2016` to `2017`.
As @Egon has pointed out, this may no longer be valid in newer versions of biblatex.

Following a look at [biblatex.def](http://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/latex/biblatex.def) I have modified `\DeclcareNameFormat` as below. This works well enough for my purposes, but I'm sure could be improved further:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
 @article{boldref, 
  AUTHOR = {Adam myLastName and Ben Bravo and Charlie Charlie and David Delta},
  TITLE = {The title},
  JOURNAL = {Journal of Examples},
  PAGES = {65--78},
  YEAR = 2017}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex, bibstyle=numeric-verb, maxnames=99,
           block=space, firstinits=true, terseinits=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem} %for \uline{}
\DeclareNameFormat{given-family}{
  \ifgiveninits
  {\ifthenelse{\equal{\namepartfamily}{myLastName}}
    {\uline{\namepartfamily\addspace\namepartgiveni\namepartsuffix}}
    {\namepartfamily\addspace\namepartgiveni\namepartsuffix}
    \ifthenelse{\value{listcount} < \value{liststop}}
    {\addcomma}
    {\ifthenelse{\ifmorenames}{~et \,al \adddot}}
    {}
  }
}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

giving:

[image]

This is with `BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2017)`

Answer (score 1):

An arguably simple answer is to use [strings](http://www.bibtex.org/Format/) and `mkbibbold` (or, alternatively, `\mkbibemph` or `\mkbibitalic`)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @string{myself={\mkbibbold{MyLastName}, \mkbibbold{MyFirstName}}}
    @article{boldref, 
        author = {Bravo, Ben and Charlie, Charlie and }#myself,
        TITLE = {The title},
        JOURNAL = {Journal of Examples},
        PAGES = {65--78},
        YEAR = 2017}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
    \nocite{*}
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

On top of being a concise way to achieve what you want, it is also very portable: just redefine the string `myself` to come back to a normal behaviour, i.e., use

```
@string{myself={MyLastName, MyFirstName}}
```

And your name will be printed normally.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to add this functionality to the .bst file. I define one simple function with the surnames of those whom I want to bold, and another function to check if a name is in the surname list. Here is the code.

```
FUNCTION{ boldees }{ "Jones and Smith" }

INTEGERS { boldptr np }
% determine if a name should be bolded
% simply modify the boldees string to change the names
%
% pops:   <author last name>
% pushes: 1 iff name is to be bolded, 0 o.w.
FUNCTION { bold.names }
{
  #1 'boldptr :=
  {  boldees num.names$ #1 + boldptr > }     %do while boldptr <= #boldees
  {  duplicate$                              %duplicate name to check since it gets popped
     boldees boldptr "{ll}" format.name$     %extract and format the name of a boldee
     =                                       %author match boldee name?
     { boldees num.names$ #2 + 'boldptr := } %true->exit with counter set > #bolded names
     { boldptr #1 + 'boldptr :=   }          %false->increment boldee name to extract
     if$                                     %is this a name to bold?
  }
  while$                                %loop through bolded name list
  pop$                                  %get rid of the extra instance of the name to check
  boldptr #1 - boldees num.names$ =     %check counter value of exit condition
  { #0 }                           
  { #1 }
  if$
}
```

and then in format.names

```
      bold.names
      {s nameptr "{{\bf\bgroup}f. {\egroup}}{vv~}{{\bf\bgroup}ll{}{\egroup}}" format.name$ 't := }
      {s nameptr "{f. }{vv~}{ll}{, jj}" format.name$ 't := }
      if$
```