# biblatex: multiple bibliographies categorised by different .bib files

Tags: biblatex, biber, subdividing

`biblatex` supports multiple bibliographies by looking up the 1) entry type, 2) keyword, or 3) category.

This is all fine, but in the use case of primary sources and secondary sources:
1) the 'type' method doesn't work,
2) it is quite tedious to key in the 'primary' and 'secondary' keywords for each `.bib` entry, and
3) declaring the sorting by category would entail typing all the primary keys in the document.

So, if I'm storing all my primary bib entries in one `.bib` file, and secondary one in another, is there a bit to tell `biblatex` to assign a keyword or category automatically to all the entries from that bib file as it imports them?  Done this way, entries can be easily swapped to and from the primary and secondary `.bib` files without fiddling individual keywords, and I don't have to type out all the primary and/or secondary entries into categories in each document.

Comment: This is s good point. I will look into this for Biber as given that it's a datasource mapping task really, it should be handled there. Shouldn't be too hard to hard to add a config file mapping facility which will add arbitrary fields to entries in only certain files.

Comment: A quick update. I have this working nicely now with biber. I will upload development binaries in the next couple of days. I'll also update this question with a full solution demonstration.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This is now implemented in Biber 0.9.8. Here is how to deal with your question. Given the sample file:

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname-primary.bib}
@BOOK{hectic,
  AUTHOR    = {Henry Hectic},
  TITLE     = {How Horticulturalists Howl},
  PUBLISHER = {Honorary Books: Henage},
  YEAR      = {2000}
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname-secondary.bib}
@BOOK{flutter,
  AUTHOR    = {Frederick Flutter},
  TITLE     = {Fraternising with Flowers},
  PUBLISHER = {Frippery Pamphlets: Folkestone},
  YEAR      = {1995}
}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\addbibresource{\jobname-primary.bib}
\addbibresource{\jobname-secondary.bib}

\begin{document}
Some citations: \cite{hectic}, \cite{flutter}.
\printbibliography[title=Primary Sources, keyword=primary]
\printbibliography[title=Secondary Sources, keyword=secondary]
\end{document}
```

You can automatically add the correct keywords to your data as Biber
reads it by using the following biber.conf file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
  <sourcemap>
    <maps datatype="bibtex" bmap_overwrite="1">
      <map>
        <per_datasource>test-primary.bib</per_datasource>
        <map_step map_field_set="KEYWORDS" map_field_value="primary"/>
      </map>
      <map>
        <per_datasource>test-secondary.bib</per_datasource>
        <map_step map_field_set="KEYWORDS" map_field_value="secondary"/>
      </map>
    </maps>
  </sourcemap>
</config>
```

This will add the necessary keywords based on the datasource names. If
you already had a KEYWORD field in your datasources which you wanted to
keep, you could use the match/replace functionality instead:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
  <sourcemap>
    <maps datatype="bibtex" map_overwrite="1">
      <map>
        <per_datasource>test-primary.bib</per_datasource>
        <map_step map_field_source="KEYWORDS" map_match="^" map_replace="primary,"/>
      </map>
      <map>
        <per_datasource>test-secondary.bib</per_datasource>
        <map_step map_field_source="KEYWORDS" map_match="^" map_replace="secondary,"/>
      </map>
    </maps>
  </sourcemap>
</config>
```

The Biber manual has been updated in 0.9.8 with documentation of the
config file format and has more examples. The format of the user
config file is a major change from 0.9.6 (and some changes also from 0.9.7) as the older format was a bit
of a mess and couldn't be extended to cope with situations like this
due to inherent limitations of the format itself. I opted for a real
XML format for flexibility. You can also validate your config file now
by passing the `--validate_config` option to Biber.

EDIT: Since biber 1.3, you there is an "append" mode for setting values in sourcemaps so it's easier like this, which deals with entries with or without an existing KEYWORDS field when you want to keep any existing values:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
  <sourcemap>
    <maps datatype="bibtex" bmap_overwrite="1">
      <map>
        <per_datasource>test-primary.bib</per_datasource>
        <map_step map_field_set="KEYWORDS" map_field_value="primary" map_append="1"/>
      </map>
      <map>
        <per_datasource>test-secondary.bib</per_datasource>
        <map_step map_field_set="KEYWORDS" map_field_value="secondary" map_append="1"/>
      </map>
    </maps>
  </sourcemap>
</config>
```

Here is the same thing using the biblatex macro interface which you can put directly in your document:

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex, overwrite]{
    \map{
      \perdatasource{test-primary.bib}
      \step[fieldset=KEYWORDS, fieldvalue=primary, append]
    }
    \map{
      \perdatasource{test-secondary.bib}
      \step[fieldset=KEYWORDS, fieldvalue=secondary, append]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to specify the `sourcemap` to handle the case where some entries have keywords and some don't?

Comment: See edits. Also, this can all be done at the document level using the `\DeclareSourcemap` macro in biblatex (this macro writes XML like the above to the .bcf file).

Comment: I have tried this with all three config files (TeXworks, MikTeX 2.9, Win7 64 bit) but biblatex does not recognise 'hectic' and 'flutter' nor the keywords 'primary' and 'secondary': `Package biblatex Warning: Keyword 'primary' not found on input line 32.` etc. I followed the instructions [here](http://robcrocombe.com/2014/10/26/how-to-reference-with-bi%C2%ADbla%C2%ADtex-and-texworks) and compiled with `pdfLaTeX+Biber+pdfLaTeX`.

Comment: @barto - I think you'll need to open a new question with a MWE.

Comment: Since this question is quite popular (vote- and view-wise) would you mind updating your answer with a way to do the sourcemapping from within the document via `\DeclareSourcemap`. In my experience this is slightly less intimidating to some users than an external XML config file.

Comment: @moewe - this is done

Comment: You should open a new question for this with a MWE so we can see what's going on.

Comment: @PLK, thanks. I just needed to change ``test-primary.bib`` to the ``\jobname-primary.bib``, a very stupid mistake. Thanks again!

Comment: It's useful to note that the `map_append` functionality (like `<map_step map_field_set="KEYWORDS" map_field_value="secondary" map_append="1"/>`) is a "string append", so if you define any additional keywords by hand in the bib file, you should add a comma at the beginning of the automatically appended value (like `map_field_value=",secondary"`). Otherwise unexpected things will happen.

Answer (score 11):

IMO the best way to deal with this is not on the level of the .bib file but with special \cite commands which allow you define ad hoc which entry goes into which bibliography. Working with two different .bib files for the two bibliographies means that you have to decide once and for all in advance which entry goes where, which isn't smart IMO.

I do something like this:

```
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{sek} 
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{prim}

\newcommand*{\citeprim}[2][]{\addtocategory{prim}{#2}\cite[#1]{#2}}
\newcommand*{\citesek}[2][]{\addtocategory{sek}{#2}\cite[#1]{#2}}
```

Now if you want to add an entry to your bibliography of primary sources, you can just type `\citeprim{citekey}`. You have to set up all the \cite command you're going to use this way. But at least for me this is makes much more sense since I only have to care about which entry goes where when I'm actually working on the document.

Comment: I agree that this is the best (only) solution if your references aren't divided by datasource. If you can categorise them by datasource separation though, doing this while reading the data is a lot easier as you don't have to decide which cite command to use for each entry.

Comment: how to use the `\nocite` command for a particular category?

Comment: but then you would need to define an alternative ``parencite``, ``autocite``, ``citeyear``, ``citeauthor``, and so on, once for each biblio...

Comment: While that's probably not worth the effort when you write a five page paper, it certainly pays off for longer projects.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this also possible with the refsegment implementation? From the Biblatex documentation:

> The refsegment environment is used in the document body to mark a reference segment. This environment is useful if you want one global bibliography which is subdivided by chapter, section, or any other part of the document. (p 74)

See also p. 101 - 103 for usage examples

Though this would of course only suit your needs if your two bibliographies apply to two distinct sections only.

Comment: No, it isn't possible. The OP was asking for a way to filter items in a bibliography by resource (bib file). `refsegment` filters a bibliography by document segment. `refsection` can be limited to a specific resource, but it is only useful for independent bibliographies. Primary/secondary categories probably don't fit into this special case.

Comment: You're right, I misunderstood the question.