# biblatex: Two .bib files with separate behavior in same document

Tags: biblatex, subdividing

I am having some trouble using `biblatex` with two bibliographies.

I am using the following option:

```
\usepackage[firstinits=true, isbn=false, url=false,  doi=false, style=ieee, defernumbers=true, sorting=ydnt, bibstyle=ieee, maxnames=5]{biblatex}
\nocite{*}
\addbibresource{bib1.bib}
\addbibresource{bib2.bib}
```

One bibliography I would like to insert in the middle of a document, with special sub-bibliography headings and special numberings.  I have actually figured out how to do this, and it works fine.  For example,

```
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,title={{\small Book Chapters}},type=incollection, keyword=DZ, prefixnumbers={B}]

\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,title={{\small Journals}},type=article, keyword=DZ, prefixnumbers={J}]
```

gives me two sub-headings (Book Chapters and Journals), and under each headings the references are listed with special numberings (i.e. B1, B2, and J1, J2, etc...).  It uses all the references in bib1.bib (the bib with keyword = DZ).  This is exactly what I want.

I would also like to include a "standard" bibliography at the end of the document using a different .bib file.  I added keywords (keywords=noDZ) to try and make life easier, and then the `\printbibliography[keyword=noDZ]` line where I want the bibliography to appear.

When I cite the article, it now displays the entire bib2 bibliography, and the numbering does not start at 1.  I suspect I am not using `\nocite` correctly.  I want the 2nd bibliography to start with [1], and only print references that were cited in the text.

Any help would be great!

[edit] Per request, here is a sample file closely reproducing what I described above (although now the inline reference reads **[2]** rather than name).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[firstinits=true, isbn=false, url=false,  doi=false, style=ieee, defernumbers=true, sorting=ydnt, bibstyle=ieee, maxnames=5]{biblatex}
\nocite{*}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname-bib1.bib}
@BOOK{hectic2000,
  AUTHOR    = {Henry Hectic},
  TITLE     = {How Horticulturalists Howl},
  PUBLISHER = {Honorary Books: Henage},
  YEAR      = {2000},
  keywords={DZ}
}
@BOOK{hectic2001,
  AUTHOR    = {Henry Hectic},
  TITLE     = {How Horticulturalists Howl},
  PUBLISHER = {Honorary Books 2: Henage},
  YEAR      = {2001},
  keywords={DZ}
}
@ARTICLE{Doe2009,
author = {Jon Doe},
journal = {Transactions on Stuff},
month = 03,
number = {3},
pages = {1--11},
title = {{Example 1}},
volume = {5},
year = {2009},
keywords={DZ}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname-bib2.bib}

@ARTICLE{Kim2012,
author = {Y Kim},
journal = {Transactions on Other Stuff},
month = 01,
number = {1},
pages = {1--11},
title = {{Example 3}},
volume = {5},
year = {2012},
keywords={noDZ}
}

@ARTICLE{Jane2010,
author = {Jane Doe},
journal = {Transactions on Stuff},
month = 01,
number = {1},
pages = {1--11},
title = {{Example 2}},
volume = {5},
year = {2010},
keywords={noDZ}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname-bib1.bib}
\addbibresource{\jobname-bib2.bib}

\begin{document}
\section{My Bib}

\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,title={{\small Book Chapters}},type=book, keyword=DZ, prefixnumbers={B}]
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,title={{\small Journals}},type=article, keyword=DZ, prefixnumbers={J}]


\section{Main Text}

Now I am citing \cite{Jane2010}.  I want new references.

\printbibheading


\printbibliography[keyword=noDZ]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: A quick note to mention this answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35279/ which deals with automatically adding keywords to different .bib files

Comment: @lockstep, per your suggestion I added a short working code that should demonstrate what I am seeing.  Thanks!

Comment: In the `Jane2010` bibentry, the comma after "month = 01"  is missing.

Comment: Please update your question so that only the remaining problems/requests are listed.

Comment: yes, typos indeed.  I found another typo in my full document that was causing similar problems.  I have modified the question...thanks @lockstep

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your example as well as in my attempt at a solution, `biblatex`/biber  don't stabilize (latexmk stops after the 5th compilation run); nevertheless, the output seems to be what you want:

- Use `\addsectionbib` for the first bibliography resource;
- Enclose your first section within a `refsection` environment, and specify the first resource as the environment's optional argument;
- Use `\nocite{*}` within the `refsection`.

EDIT: The solution doesn't rely on keywords, so I omitted them.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[firstinits=true, isbn=false, url=false,  doi=false, style=ieee, defernumbers=true, sorting=ydnt, bibstyle=ieee, maxnames=5]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname-bib1.bib}
@BOOK{hectic2000,
  AUTHOR= {Henry Hectic},
  TITLE = {How Horticulturalists Howl},
  PUBLISHER = {Honorary Books: Henage},
  YEAR  = {2000},
}
@BOOK{hectic2001,
  AUTHOR= {Henry Hectic},
  TITLE = {How Horticulturalists Howl},
  PUBLISHER = {Honorary Books 2: Henage},
  YEAR  = {2001},
}
@ARTICLE{Doe2009,
author = {Jon Doe},
journal = {Transactions on Stuff},
month = 03,
number = {3},
pages = {1--11},
title = {{Example 1}},
volume = {5},
year = {2009},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname-bib2.bib}
@ARTICLE{Kim2012,
author = {Y Kim},
journal = {Transactions on Other Stuff},
month = 01,
number = {1},
pages = {1--11},
title = {{Example 3}},
volume = {5},
year = {2012},
}
@ARTICLE{Jane2010,
author = {Jane Doe},
journal = {Transactions on Stuff},
month = 01,
number = {1},
pages = {1--11},
title = {{Example 2}},
volume = {5},
year = {2010},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addsectionbib{\jobname-bib1.bib}
\addbibresource{\jobname-bib2.bib}

\begin{document}

\begin{refsection}[\jobname-bib1.bib]

\nocite{*}

\section{My Bib}

\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,title={{\small Book Chapters}},type=book,prefixnumbers={B}]
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,title={{\small Journals}},type=article,prefixnumbers={J}]

\end{refsection}

\section{Main Text}

Now I am citing \cite{Jane2010}.  I want new references.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: running this code seems to handle bib2 correctly, but now bib1 does not display at all.

Comment: @1yen My output possibly requires several LaTeX/biber runs.

Comment: thanks, but now I think your comment is revealing a more fundamental problem I have...which relates to biber.  I was using bibtex to compile up to now.

Comment: @1yen Shold work with (several!) BibTeX runs, too. Look at your log file teo see which files must be run with BibTeX.

Comment: There was a (hopefully resolved) issue with defernumbers resulting in endless cycles which has been addressed in the biblatex 2.6 version beta on sourceforge.

Comment: many thanks @lockstep...looking into the log file did indeed reveal instructions to bibtex another file.  I never knew about that, but now it works the way I had hoped.  I use texshop and Latexian, is there a way to have it automatically run bibtex on the "extra" aux file?

Comment: @1yen Don't know about Latexian, but there *are* tools (e.g., latexmk) that will automatically detect which runs are necessary.

Comment: With biber, you don't need to run on any other files - it's all done in one pass of the one (.bcf) file. I tested your example with the biblatex 2.6 beta and biber 1.5 and it gives the results which @lockstep demonstrates.