# biblatex filter on arbitrary field

Tags: biblatex

We maintain a bibtex file with all publications from our group. We use the annote field to separate the publications into several groups, e.g. *Journal Papers* or *Other Papers*. This makes the entries look like this:

```
@article{something_2011,
    Author = {Author, Some and Other, An},
    Title = {Here be dragons},
    Journal = {Whatever journal},
    Pages = {123-234},
    Volume = {1},
    Year = {2000},
    Annote = {Other Peer Reviewed Paper}
}
```

We then have a tex file that looks something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\addbibresource{author1_Books.bib}
\addbibresource{author1_OtherPeerReviewedPapers.bib}
\addbibresource{author1_OtherPapers.bib}
\addbibresource{author1_JournalPapers.bib}

\begin{document}
  \nocite{*}
  \printbibliography[title={Books}]
  \printbibliography[title={Other Peer Reviewed Papers}]
  \printbibliography[title={Other Papers}]
  \printbibliography[title={Journal Papers}]
\end{document}
```

The above tex files prints all publications into all four bibliographies. So we want to use the content of the annote field to group the entries. But biblatex only filters on segment, type, subtype, category, keyword or a combination of those, but not on arbitrary fields. Is it possible to have biblatex filter on the annote field?

Comment: You can let Biber figure out which work came from which `.bib` file, if that helps you with [biblatex: multiple bibliographies categorised by different .bib files](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35279/35864), [Printing only one bib file](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/162660/35864). Alternatively you can check out bibfilters, see §3.7.9 *Bibliography Filters and Checks* of the `biblatex` doc.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Note that `annote` is an alias for `annotation`, so the answer uses `annotation` instead.

You can create `bibcheck`s with almost arbitrary logic. See §3.7.9 *Bibliography Filters and Checks* of the [`biblatex` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf).
A `bibcheck` will contain the special directive `\skipentry` to discard a particular entry, all entries that do not get to `\skipentry` will be displayed. (So in a way you don't explicitly tell `biblatex` which entries you want, you mark those that you don't want.)

With `\iffieldequalstr` you can check for field contents. Putting that together you can use

```
\defbibcheck{annotebar}{\iffieldequalstr{annotation}{bar}{}{\skipentry}}
\defbibcheck{annotefoo}{\iffieldequalstr{annotation}{foo}{}{\skipentry}}
```

to obtain only those entries with an `annotation` equal to `bar` and `foo`, respectively.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[bibencoding=auto,backend=biber,babel=other]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Bara2006,
  address = {New York},
  author = {Bara, Judith},
  publisher = {Routledge},
  title = {English Citation entry},
  year = {2006},
  annote = {foo},
}
@book{Bara2007,
  address = {New York},
  author = {Bara, Judith},
  publisher = {Routledge},
  title = {Another English Citation entry},
  year = {2007},
  annote = {bar},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\defbibcheck{annotebar}{\iffieldequalstr{annotation}{bar}{}{\skipentry}}
\defbibcheck{annotefoo}{\iffieldequalstr{annotation}{foo}{}{\skipentry}}

\begin{document}
\parencite{Bara2006,Bara2007}
\printbibliography[check=annotebar]
\printbibliography[check=annotefoo]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer. I actually missed the part to define arbitrary filters in the biblatex documentation. I read the beginning of the referenced chapter §3.7.9, but I somehow overlook it. I'll give it a try

Answer (score 6):

Here is a solution using filters and categories from `biblatex`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{aaa,
    Author = {Aaa, John and Other, An},
    Title = {Here be dragons},
    Journal = {Whatever journal},
    Pages = {123-234},
    Volume = {1},
    Year = {2000},
    Annote = {Journal Papers}
}
@article{bbb,
    Author = {Bbb, Alexandra},
    Title = {Dunjeon \& Dragons},
    Journal = {A journal},
    Pages = {12-24},
    Volume = {1},
    Year = {2001},
    Annote = {Other Papers}
}
@article{ccc,
    Author = {Ccc, Jules},
    Title = {A small title},
    Journal = {A book},
    Pages = {1023-1026},
    Volume = {2},
    Year = {2016},
    Annote = {Books}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{Books}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{JournalPapers}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{OtherPapers}
\DeclareIndexFieldFormat{Books}{%
  \ifstrequal{Books}{#1}
  {\addtocategory{Books}{\thefield{entrykey}}}
  {
    \ifstrequal{Journal Papers}{#1}
    {\addtocategory{JournalPapers}{\thefield{entrykey}}}
    {
      \ifstrequal{Other Papers}{#1}
      {\addtocategory{OtherPapers}{\thefield{entrykey}}}
      {}
    }
  }
}
\AtDataInput{\indexfield[Books]{annotation}}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[category=Books,title={Books}]
\printbibliography[category=JournalPapers,title={Journal Papers}]
\printbibliography[category=OtherPapers,title={Other Papers}]
\end{document}
```