# bibcheck not working

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibtex, zotero

I tried to filter my bibliography in line with what I read on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/333682/biblatex-filter-on-arbitrary-field). MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[                  % for biblatex
    backend = biber,
    sorting = none, 
    defernumbers,
    style = numeric-comp %ieee
           ]{biblatex} 
\defbibcheck{latents}{\iffieldequalstr{groups}{Latent}{}{\skipentry}}

\addbibresource{refs.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite{foo}

\printbibliography[check=latents]

\end{document}
```

refs.bib:

```
@online{foo,
  title = {A thing},
  author = {Me},
  date = {2021-12},
  groups = {Latent}
}
```

Error: Empty bibliography on input line 18.

I assume this is because the "groups" field isn't really a thing BibTex recognizes. I can get around it with

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=groups, final]
      \step[fieldset=keywords, origfieldval]
    }
  }
}
```

And just filtering by keyword in the normal way, but is there a solution that doesn't require me to mess with keywords?

Comment: Why specifically are you worried about "messing with keywords"? The problem - as you have mentioned yourself - is that `biblatex` does not know a `group` field. The standard way around this problem is either to map to a different field or to register the `group` field. The latter might be the cleanest solution, but requires the most work. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/163303/35864 for details.

Comment: Any news here? It would be really helpful if you could explain what exactly your constraints for a solution are.

Comment: I just ended up messing with keywords.