# Change Natbib into Bibtex, including ibid.-style

Tags: bibtex, natbib, multibib

I'm new here. My problem is, that I'm using `natbib` but I need an `ibid.` function. Natbib does not provide something similar, therefore I must change to `bibtex`. I have two bibliographies. 
Now i wrote the whole paper and have to turn it in soon, but I need this ibid. function.

My preamble:

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{multibib}
\usepackage{url}
\newcites{online}{Web Archive}
```

If a paper goes into the normal bibliography I write `\citep{Arthur2008}` and if it has to go into the bibliography "Web Archive" I write `\citeponline{Arthur2008}`.

Now I have to change the whole think into biblatex to use the ibid. function (`authoryear-ibid`). Is there a possibility I can change only change the preambel, so everything stays the same, without changing \citep / \citeponline within the paper... Because this would mean soo much work..

I would prob. find it out myself, but I'm really in a hurry...

Thank you very much for all help

Comment: More or less a combination-duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/427970/how-do-i-transition-from-natbib-to-biblatex and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/149313/is-there-a-disadvantage-to-using-natbib-true-with-biblatex. If you use `\usepackage[natbib=true]{biblatex}` then you can use `\citet`, `\citep` etc. in your document with `biblatex`.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Yes, this seems pretty easy. But my problem is more how I can still use \citeponline which is than transferred into a second Bibliography like I did it with multibib. Because I have rughly about 150x \citeponline within my paper and to change all of it would mean a lot of time...

Comment: If all the `online` entries are actually specified as `@online` or a similar distinct type in your `.bib` file, then you can just replace all `\citeponline` commands by `\citep` (you can do that in a few seconds with the search and replace function of your editor) and then use `\printbibliography[type=online]` for your online subbibliography and `\printbibliography[nottype=online]` for the bibliography with all other types.

Comment: If the online entries are in a different `.bib` file you can also cite them with regular `\citep` and print the different bib files are separate bibliographies, see for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/358963/one-bibliography-section-per-bib-file-biblatex. For this the entries do not need to be of the same type, but they need to be in different `.bib` files.

Comment: If the online entries are not a distinct type (for example an `@article` could be online or not) and they are not in different `.bib` files, then you can add a category to each individual online entry and print a bibliography for that category only. You could automate that by defining `\citeponline` as first `\addtocategory{online}{citekey}` and then `\citep{citekey}`. I could expand that into an answer if this is your situation (and when I have time...).

Comment: Great! It worked out with the two distinct types! Easy! wow, thanks to you I can turn it in tonight...