# Multiple bibliographies without repetitions

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, multibib

I know of `multibib` and some related packages but, as far as I understand, they do not seem to fit perfectly my needs.

I would like to do the following. A `main bibliography` would list all items cited in the main text. A `second bibliography` will list all items cited in footnotes (and, ideally, in other designated environments, such as remarks). The basic idea is to have a short bibliography containing vital references and a longer one containing other references that are not vital but may be intersting.

This is not overly difficult using `multibib`. My main problem is that I would like to have items cited in the main text and in footnotes to be listed only once in the main bibliography.

Here is a pseudo-code of what I would like to have.

```
\documentclass{article}
% Here a definition of the \citespecial command.
\begin{document}
Some text \cite{a,b} and there a footnote\footnote{\citespecial{b,c,d}}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

The result should have `a, b` in the main bibliography and `c, d` in the second one but not `b` since it already appears in the main bibliography.

I am currently a `bibtex` user but I can consider using `biblatex`.

For the record, here is a `MWE`using `multibib`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents,multibib}
\usepackage{multibib}
\newcites{secd}{Secondary References}
\begin{filecontents}{essmult.bib}
@ARTICLE{a,
  author       = "Doe, J.",
  title        = "Title, Part 1",
  journal      = "Interesting Journal 1",
  year         = "1991",
  volume       = "1",
  pages        = "1--11",
}
@ARTICLE{b,
  author       = "Doe, J.",
  title        = "Title, Part 2",
  journal      = "Interesting Journal 2",
  year         = "1992",
  volume       = "2",
  pages        = "2--22",
}
@ARTICLE{c,
  author       = "Doe, J.",
  title        = "Title, Part 3",
  journal      = "Interesting Journal 3",
  year         = "1993",
  volume       = "3",
  pages        = "3--33",
}
@ARTICLE{d,
  author       = "Doe, J.",
  title        = "Title, Part 4 ",
  journal      = "Interesting Journal 4",
  year         = "1993",
  volume       = "4",
  pages        = "4--44",
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
Some text \cite{a,b} and there a footnote\footnote{\protect\citesecd{b,c,d}}
\bibliographystylesecd{plain}
\bibliographysecd{essmult}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{essmult}
\end{document}
```

giving the following result, showing the unfortunate repetition that I am trying to avoid

[image]

Comment: Since you've added the `biblatex` tag, are you open to solutions using `biblatex`? It's much easier to do this using it. See e.g. [biblatex: multiple bibliographies categorised by different .bib files](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35279)

Comment: @AlanMunn Yes I am also open to `biblatex`. The link is most useful. If you expand and add an answer, I could accept it.