# Biblatex split bibliography and use different cite styles

Tags: biblatex, citing, splitbib

I'm new here. I've used LaTeX for same of my articles and until now I was able to solve my problems on my own. But now I'm stuck.

I've to split my bibliography in reliable and non-reliable sources. The reliable sources should be cited with the alphabetic style inline. The non-reliable should be cited as footnote with verbose-note style.
Both should also be printed in their own bibliography.

I've used this answere: [Biblatex: Two bibliographies with different styles and sortings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/299064/biblatex-two-bibliographies-with-different-styles-and-sortings)
I manged to split the bibliography and use the given different styles.

I'm stuck on how to tell the scondary bibliography to use verbose-note for my footcite.

I hope someone can help me!

Many Thanks in advance.
(My MWE is the answere of the given link)

Answer (score 2):

A nice guy hinted me on using `\footfullcite{}`. That was exactly what I'm looking for!

Comment: Of course that is by no means an automatic solution - the one you linked to chooses the style automatically based on keywords. That is a whole lot more involved. Especially if you want some citations in footnotes and others not. (What do you do if you have `\cite{foo,bar}` where `foo` should get an alphabetic style and `bar` should go to the footnote.) Then things become a bit more intricate - even more than changing between numeric and alphabetic.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a complete solution, but I hope it might be useful.

The main idea is to compose a list of "unreliable" sources

```
\gdef\unreliable{}
\listadd{\unreliable}{LinkD01}
\listadd{\unreliable}{LinkC04}
```

and then to use the following citation command, which has the usual format `\mycite[prenote][postnote]{key}`:

```
\usepackage{xparse}
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\mycite}{oom}{%
  \ifinlist{#3}{\unreliable} %in the list of 'reliables'?
    {\IfNoValueTF{#2}
      {\IfNoValueTF{#1}
        {\footfullcite{#3}}
        {\footfullcite[#1]{#3}}}
      {\footfullcite[#1][#2]{#3}}}
    {\IfNoValueTF{#2}
      {\IfNoValueTF{#1}
        {\cite{#3}}
        {\cite[#1]{#3}}}
      {\cite[#1][#2]{#3}}}}
```

As you see, `\mycite` doesn't fully support the citing of several keys.

If you add keys to the `\unreliable` list manually using `\listadd`, this is basically enough to solve the problem. But it's also possible to populate the list automatically. To do this we first define a special `bibenvironment`

```
\defbibenvironment{counting}
  {}
  {}
  {\listxadd{\unreliable}{\thefield{entrykey}}}
```

and then fill in the list in the beginning of the document:

```
\begingroup%
  \makeatletter%
  \def\blx@driver#1{}%
  \printbibliography[env=counting,heading=none,keyword=secondary]%
  \makeatother%
\endgroup%
```

The list will contain all sources with the keyword `secondary`.

For I don't know what reason the `\ifinlist` command didn't work for me in this automatic case. So in the MWE below I use instead the following command:

```
\newtoggle{tempa}
\newcommand{\ifunreliable}[3]{%
  \renewcommand*{\do}[1]{%
    \togglefalse{tempa}%
    \ifstrequal{#1}{##1}
      {\toggletrue{tempa}\listbreak}
      {}}%
  \dolistloop{\unreliable}%
  \iftoggle{tempa}{#2}{#3}%
  }
```

Full **MWE** with automatic list filling:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{biblatextest1.bib}
@BOOK{BookA03,
  author    = {Author Aaa},
  title     = {Some Title},
  publisher = {Some Publisher},
  year      = 2003,
}
@BOOK{BookB02,
  author    = {Author Bbb},
  title     = {Some Title},
  publisher = {Some Publisher},
  year      = 2002,
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{biblatextest2.bib}
@MISC{LinkC04,
  author  = {Author Ccc},  
  title   = {Some Title},
  year    = 2004,
  url     = {www.test1.com/bild.jpg},
}
@MISC{LinkD01,
  author  = {Author Ddd},
  title   = {Some Title},
  year    = 2001,
  url     = {www.test2.com/bild.jpg},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style = alphabetic, labelnumber, defernumbers = true,  backend = biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatextest1.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatextest2.bib}

\usepackage{hyperref}

%Append keywords to identify different bibliography entries.
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex, overwrite]{
    \map{
      \perdatasource{biblatextest1.bib}
      \step[fieldset=KEYWORDS, fieldvalue=primary, append]
    }
    \map{
      \perdatasource{biblatextest2.bib}
      \step[fieldset=KEYWORDS, fieldvalue=secondary, append]
    }
  }
}

\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}

\defbibenvironment{bibliographyNUM}
  {\list
     {\printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
        \printfield{prefixnumber}%
        \printfield{labelnumber}}}
     {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\labelnumberwidth}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}%
      \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{\hss##1}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}

\assignrefcontextkeyws[sorting=none]{secondary}

\gdef\unreliable{}
\defbibenvironment{counting}
  {}
  {}
  {\listxadd{\unreliable}{\thefield{entrykey}}}

\newtoggle{tempa}
\newcommand{\ifunreliable}[3]{%
  \renewcommand*{\do}[1]{%
    \togglefalse{tempa}%
    \ifstrequal{#1}{##1}
      {\toggletrue{tempa}\listbreak}
      {}}%
  \dolistloop{\unreliable}%
  \iftoggle{tempa}{#2}{#3}%
  }
\usepackage{xparse}
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\mycite}{oom}{%
  \ifunreliable{#3}
    {\IfNoValueTF{#2}
      {\IfNoValueTF{#1}
        {\footfullcite{#3}}
        {\footfullcite[#1]{#3}}}
      {\footfullcite[#1][#2]{#3}}}
    {\IfNoValueTF{#2}
      {\IfNoValueTF{#1}
        {\cite{#3}}
        {\cite[#1]{#3}}}
      {\cite[#1][#2]{#3}}}}

\begin{document}
\begingroup%
  \makeatletter%
  \def\blx@driver#1{}%
  \printbibliography[env=counting,heading=none,keyword=secondary]%
  \makeatother%
\endgroup%

The first two citations \mycite{LinkD01} and \mycite{BookB02}. 
The others are \mycite{LinkC04} and \mycite{BookA03}.

\printbibliography[title=Bibliography, keyword=primary]

\newrefcontext[sorting=none]
\printbibliography[env=bibliographyNUM,title=References, keyword=secondary, resetnumbers]
\end{document}
```