# Biblatex: Two bibliographies with different styles and sortings II

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, sorting, styles

The answer of [moewe](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/35864/moewe) to the question [Biblatex: Two bibliographies with different styles and sortings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/299064/biblatex-two-bibliographies-with-different-styles-and-sortings) is almost what I want to achieve. Because of the large number of entries in my document, I would prefer to use the style `numeric-comp` instead of just `numeric`. How can I get this?

Extended MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{biblatextest1.bib}
@BOOK{BookA03,
  author    = {Author Aaa},
  title     = {Some Title},
  publisher = {Some Publisher},
  year      = 2003,
}
@BOOK{BookB02,
  author    = {Author Bbb},
  title     = {Some Title},
  publisher = {Some Publisher},
  year      = 2002,
}
@BOOK{BookB09,
    author    = {Author Jjj},
    title     = {Some Title},
    publisher = {Some Publisher},
    year      = 2002,
}
@BOOK{BookB10,
    author    = {Author Kkk},
    title     = {Some Title},
    publisher = {Some Publisher},
    year      = 2002,
}
@BOOK{BookB11,
    author    = {Author Lll},
    title     = {Some Title},
    publisher = {Some Publisher},
    year      = 2002,
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{biblatextest2.bib}
@MISC{LinkC04,
  author  = {Author Ccc},  
  title   = {Some Title},
  year    = 2004,
  url     = {www.test1.com/bild.jpg},
}
@MISC{LinkD01,
  author  = {Author Ddd},
  title   = {Some Title},
  year    = 2001,
  url     = {www.test2.com/bild.jpg},
}
@MISC{LinkD05,
    author  = {Author Eee},  
    title   = {Some Title},
    year    = 2004,
    url     = {www.test3.com/bild.jpg},
}
@MISC{LinkD06,
    author  = {Author Fff},
    title   = {Some Title},
    year    = 2001,
    url     = {www.test4.com/bild.jpg},
}
@MISC{LinkD07,
    author  = {Author Ggg},  
    title   = {Some Title},
    year    = 2004,
    url     = {www.test5.com/bild.jpg},
}
@MISC{LinkD08,
    author  = {Author Hhh},
    title   = {Some Title},
    year    = 2001,
    url     = {www.test6.com/bild.jpg},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style = alphabetic, labelnumber, defernumbers = true,  backend = biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatextest1.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatextest2.bib}

\usepackage{hyperref}

%Append keywords to identify different bibliography entries.
\DeclareSourcemap{
    \maps[datatype=bibtex, overwrite]{
        \map{
            \perdatasource{biblatextest1.bib}
            \step[fieldset=KEYWORDS, fieldvalue=primary, append]
        }
        \map{
            \perdatasource{biblatextest2.bib}
            \step[fieldset=KEYWORDS, fieldvalue=secondary, append]
        }
    }
}

\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}
\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
    \printtext[bibhyperref]{%
        \printfield{labelprefix}%
        \ifkeyword{secondary}
        {\printfield{labelnumber}}
        {\printfield{labelalpha}%
            \printfield{extraalpha}}}}


\defbibenvironment{bibliographyNUM}
{\list
    {\printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
            \printfield{prefixnumber}%
            \printfield{labelnumber}}}
    {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\labelnumberwidth}%
        \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
        \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
        \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
        \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
        \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}%
    \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{\hss##1}}
{\endlist}
{\item}

\assignrefcontextkeyws[sorting=none]{secondary}
\begin{document}

    The first two citations \cite{LinkD07,LinkC04} and \cite{BookB10,BookB11,BookB02,BookB09}. 
    The others are \cite{LinkD08,LinkD01,LinkD05,LinkD06} and \cite{BookA03}.

    \printbibliography[title=Bibliography, keyword=primary]

    \newrefcontext[sorting=none]
    \printbibliography[env=bibliographyNUM,title=References, keyword=secondary, resetnumbers]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Did you misname the author of the answer or did you post the wrong link? There is no answer by moewe to the question you linked. There is a relevant-seeming answer by lockstep, but I don't know if it is the one you meant to reference or not.

Comment: Sorry, I posted the wrong link. But now is correct. Thank you for your remark.

Comment: @cfr. In short, I need two bibliographies. The first one in `alphabetic` style sorted by author name and the second one in `numeric-comp` style sorted by citations order.

Comment: Mhhh, to do the same with `numeric-comp` would be quite a bit more complicated, since `numeric-comp`'s cite macros are vastly more complicated than `numeric`'s. What happens if you cite numeric and alphabetic citations in the same `\cite`?

Comment: @moewe . I know, I have checked the codes of `alphabetic.cbx`, `numeric.cbx` and `numeric-comp.cbx`. It seems to work well: `The first two citations \cite{BookB10,LinkD07,LinkC04} and \cite{BookB10,BookB11,LinkD07,LinkC04,BookB02,BookB09}. 
    The others are \cite{LinkD08,LinkD01,BookA03,LinkD05,LinkD06} and \cite{BookA03,LinkC04}.` Just replacing `style=alphabetic` with `bibstyle = alphabetic, citestyle = numeric` gives the same result. But with `bibstyle = alphabetic, citestyle = numeric-comp` is the entire citation style `numeric`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I managed to get somewhere based on the `numeric-comp` and than trying to bring `labelalpha` information to the `shorthand` field, which is dealt with natively by the `numeric-comp`, so you don't need to redefine the `cite` macros/commands.

I initially tried to do this in the source map, but somehow it didn't work, so I ended up using `\AtEveryCitekey` for that.

You will probably still have to tune sorting. And you will also notice that the mixed citation of primary and secondary references is less than ideal (I couldn't find out what was determining the sortcite in this case). But the overall result looks reasonable.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{biblatextest1.bib}
@BOOK{BookA03,
  author    = {Author Aaa},
  title     = {Some Title},
  publisher = {Some Publisher},
  year      = 2003,
}
@BOOK{BookB02,
  author    = {Author Bbb},
  title     = {Some Title},
  publisher = {Some Publisher},
  year      = 2002,
}
@BOOK{BookB09,
    author    = {Author Jjj},
    title     = {Some Title},
    publisher = {Some Publisher},
    year      = 2002,
}
@BOOK{BookB10,
    author    = {Author Kkk},
    title     = {Some Title},
    publisher = {Some Publisher},
    year      = 2002,
}
@BOOK{BookB11,
    author    = {Author Lll},
    title     = {Some Title},
    publisher = {Some Publisher},
    year      = 2002,
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{biblatextest2.bib}
@MISC{LinkC04,
  author  = {Author Ccc},  
  title   = {Some Title},
  year    = 2004,
  url     = {www.test1.com/bild.jpg},
}
@MISC{LinkD01,
  author  = {Author Ddd},
  title   = {Some Title},
  year    = 2001,
  url     = {www.test2.com/bild.jpg},
}
@MISC{LinkD05,
    author  = {Author Eee},  
    title   = {Some Title},
    year    = 2004,
    url     = {www.test3.com/bild.jpg},
}
@MISC{LinkD06,
    author  = {Author Fff},
    title   = {Some Title},
    year    = 2001,
    url     = {www.test4.com/bild.jpg},
}
@MISC{LinkD07,
    author  = {Author Ggg},  
    title   = {Some Title},
    year    = 2004,
    url     = {www.test5.com/bild.jpg},
}
@MISC{LinkD08,
    author  = {Author Hhh},
    title   = {Some Title},
    year    = 2001,
    url     = {www.test6.com/bild.jpg},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style = numeric-comp, labelalpha, defernumbers]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatextest1.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatextest2.bib}

\usepackage{hyperref}

%Append keywords to identify different bibliography entries.
\DeclareSourcemap{
    \maps[datatype=bibtex, overwrite]{
        \map{
            \perdatasource{biblatextest1.bib}
            \step[fieldset=KEYWORDS, fieldvalue=primary]
        }
        \map{
            \perdatasource{biblatextest2.bib}
            \step[fieldset=KEYWORDS, fieldvalue=secondary]
        }
    }
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\labelalphatoshorthand}{\csdef{abx@field@shorthand}{\strfield{labelprefix}\strfield{labelalpha}\strfield{extraalpha}}}
\makeatother

\AtEveryCitekey{\ifkeyword{primary}{\labelalphatoshorthand}{}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{labelalphawidth}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}

\defbibenvironment{bibliographyALPHA}
  {\list
     {\printtext[labelalphawidth]{%
        \printfield{labelprefix}%
        \printfield{labelalpha}%
        \printfield{extraalpha}}}
     {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\labelalphawidth}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}%
      \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{##1\hss}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}

\begin{document}

The first two citations \cite{LinkD07,LinkC04} and
\cite{BookB10,BookB11,BookB02,BookB09}.

Mixing both primary and secondary
\cite{LinkD08,LinkD01,LinkD05,LinkD06,BookB10,BookB11,BookB02,BookB09}.

The others are \cite{LinkD08,LinkD01,LinkD05,LinkD06,LinkD07}
and \cite{BookA03}.

\printbibliography[env=bibliographyALPHA, title=Bibliography, keyword=primary]

\newrefcontext
\printbibliography[title=References, keyword=secondary, resetnumbers]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Off-topic: notice I removed your `append` instructions from your `DeclareSourcemap` steps. The idea of appending is a good one. But suppose you have one field with a keyword `mykeyword` and append `primary` to it. You will get `mykeywordprimary`, which is neither `mykeyword` nor `primary`, and your keyword based mechanism for separating the bibliographies will fail (actually you will have missing bibliography entries). So to do that, you would have to include a comma between the keywords and handle the case of the field being empty or not, and so on.

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I was looking for. I considered to define firstly the style`numeric-comp`instead of `alphabetic`, but I thought it was more difficult to redefine the macros/commands. Actually I do not need to mixed citations, but it is nice to know, that it also works. Is there a reason why did you remove the option `backend=biber` from `biblatex` package definition? I have also included the option `[labelprefix=a]` to `\newrefcontext` (it works with the option `backend=biber`).

Comment: In case of the ranges, it produces `a2-a4` or `a2-a6`. Is it possible to remove the 2nd `labelprefix` to obtain `a2-4` or `a2-6`, but maintaining the `labelprefix` in the bibliography, that is: `[a4]` or `[a6]`?

Comment: @Ñako, the reason I removed the option `backend=biber` is that it is already the default. But there is no harm in leaving it, if you prefer.

Comment: @Ñako, as to your question about the ranges, I wouldn't know, but perhaps someone else might. The question posed here was addressed, I believe. If you have another one, you can always ask a follow-up question with a link to this one.

Comment: for some reason `\newrefcontext[labelprefix=a]` has not compile without the option `backend=biber`, despite `biber` is the default option in my TexStudio.

Comment: By the way, I found how to remove the "2nd" `labelprefix`; redefining the `cite:dump` macro of `numeric-comp.cbx` and erasing `\printtext[labelprefix]{\cbx@lastprefix}`, that is,
 `\renewbibmacro*{cite:dump}{%
 \ifnumgreater{\value{cbx@tempcnta}}{0}
 {\ifnumgreater{\value{cbx@tempcnta}}{1}
  {\bibrangedash}
  {\multicitedelim}%
  \bibhyperref[\cbx@lastkey]{%
   \ifdef\cbx@lastprefix
   {}
   {}%
   \printtext[labelnumber]{\cbx@lastnumber}
  }}
 {}%
 \setcounter{cbx@tempcnta}{0}%
 \global\undef\cbx@lastprefix}`

Comment: ,the `\strfield{extraalpha}` of `\newcommand*{\labelalphatoshorthand}` produces a number rather than a letter, in case of two or more works by the same author which were all published in the same year. To solve this minimal issue, I just replace it with `\printfield{extraalpha}`. This gives the right output, but is this a good practice? What would be a proper way to achieve the right output?Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Ñako Yes, in this case, `\strfield{extraalpha}` will produce a number and `\printfield{extraalpha}` is its "formatted" version, which by default will be a letter. Either is good practice, depending on the desired result.