# Mix up alphabetic and numeric style bibtex

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, biber

I using Bibtex and Biber to set up my Bibliography. I have configure the alphabetic stlye. So the normal \cite{} will be shown as [XXX00] with the author and the year. The Problem what exist: I have online websites as sources and lot of them have no author or year so they will be shown up as [].
Is there an oportunity to mix the alphabetic style with the numeric?
So the articles which includes an author and a year will be shown up alphabetic and all others numeric?

Thanks for the answers.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: You wrote, "I us[e] Bibtex and Biber to set up my bibliography." BibTeX and Biber are two external programs; one typically uses one or the other, *but not both*, to create the formatted bibliography. Please clarify what you're doing.

Comment: Note that just because you cite material from webpages doesn't mean that no  author(s) exist: If nothing else, you can always list the name of the organization that runs the website as the (corporate) author. Also, if the websites in question are related to news organizations or reporting about social issues and other current events, it's usually easy to ascertain in which `year` the webpage was created.

Comment: i use only biber.

Comment: Then please edit your posting to remove the `bibtex` tag and all mentions of BibTeX. Or, do mention that you use the `biblatex` package.

Answer (score 1):

Copying the idea from [Biblatex: Two bibliographies with different styles and sortings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/299064/35864) and adapting it to filter by type (`@online`) instead of `keyword` we get

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style = alphabetic, labelnumber, defernumbers = true,  backend = biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}
\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperref]{%
    \printfield{labelprefix}%
    \ifentrytype{online}
      {\printfield{labelnumber}}
      {\printfield{labelalpha}%
       \printfield{extraalpha}}}}

\defbibenvironment{bibliographyNUM}
  {\list
     {\printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
        \printfield{labelprefix}%
        \printfield{labelnumber}}}
     {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\labelnumberwidth}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}%
      \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{\hss##1}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{BookA03,
  author    = {Author Aaa},
  title     = {Some Title},
  journal   = {Some Journal},
  year      = 2003,
}
@BOOK{BookB02,
  author    = {Author Bbb},
  title     = {Some Title},
  publisher = {Some Publisher},
  year      = 2002,
}
@online{LinkC04,
  author  = {Author Ccc},  
  title   = {Some Title},
  year    = 2004,
  url     = {http://www.example.com/1},
}
@online{LinkD01,
  author  = {Author Ddd},
  title   = {Some Title},
  year    = 2001,
  url     = {http://www.example.com/2},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
The first two citations \cite{LinkD01} and \cite{BookB02}. 
The others are \cite{LinkC04} and \cite{BookA03}.

\printbibliography[title=Bibliography, nottype=online]

\newrefcontext[sorting=none]
\printbibliography[env=bibliographyNUM, title={Online References}, type=online, resetnumbers]
\end{document}
```

[image: Split bibliography with alphabetic and numeric style.]

Answer (score 0):

I found out, that there is the option label for the @online{} articles. I can use this to fix my problem.