# Different colors for each bib file and custom prefix

Tags: biblatex, pdftex, color, multibib

I have multiple bib files. I would like to use different text colors for all the references mentioned in different bib files. 
Secondly, i would like a custom prefix for each bib file.

Please let me know how can I do it?

The result should be similar to as follows:

[R1] uses [O1] and [R2] is based on [O2].

References

[R1]  .....

[R2]  .....

Other References

[O1] ....

[O2] ....

Color of references mentioned in section "References" will be black, where as color of references mentioned in section "Other references" will be blue.

Comment: You have tagged the question  with both `biblatex` and `multibib`. Those two packages are incompatible (`biblatex` being a complete re-implementation of BibTeX's bibliography/citation approach and `multibib` being a BibTeX-based solution). Do you want to use `biblatex` (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5091/35864, you would not be able to keep using your current `.bst` bibliography style) or `multibib`?

Comment: Any solution can work for me....if it is  biblatex, it will be preferable...

Comment: Please do not change the question significantly after you have already gotten an answer. Please ask a new question making it clear that you insist on a solution with `elsarticle`, but leave this question in its original state. See https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7678/35864

Comment: Ok....I will post another question specifically for elsarticle

Comment: Thank you very much for rolling back the `elsarticle` edit.

Comment: No problem...Thanks for guiding me a right way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can split the bibliography by `.bib` file (something that is not necessarily very semantic) following [biblatex: multiple bibliographies categorised by different .bib files](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35279/35864) and [separating bibliography items based on resource file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/362114/35864) (the second link shows how to deal with existing `keyword`s).

Adding the additional letter into the label is then as simple as issuing `\newrefcontext[labelprefix=<prefix>]` before the `\printbibliography`. See [Biblatex entry renumbering and prefixing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/434348/35864), [Custom citation label](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/463449/35864), [Biblatex with sections, prefix, and reversed order](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/349954/35864), [Separate bibliographies for phdthesis and mastersthesis in biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/369309/35864).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric, defernumbers]{biblatex}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex,overwrite]{
    \map{
      \perdatasource{\jobname-1.bib}
      \step[fieldset=keywords, fieldvalue={,file1}, append]
    }
    \map{
      \perdatasource{\jobname-2.bib}
      \step[fieldset=keywords, fieldvalue={,file2}, append]
    }
  }
}

\newcommand*{\mkbibcolourcite}[1]{%
  \ifkeyword{file2}
    {\textcolor{blue}{#1}}
    {#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{\mkbibbrackets{\mkbibcolourcite{#1}}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{colourcite}{\mkbibcolourcite{#1}}

\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperref]{%
    \printtext[colourcite]{%
      \printfield{labelprefix}%
      \printfield{labelnumber}%
      \ifbool{bbx:subentry}
        {\printfield{entrysetcount}}
        {}}}}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname-1.bib}
@book{book1,
  author = {Onymous, Anne},
  title  = {First Bibliography: Category 1},
  date   = {2000},
}
@book{book3,
  author   = {Scribbler, Sarah},
  title    = {First Bibliography Again: Category A and B},
  date     = {1899},
  keywords = {cata},
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname-2.bib}
@book{book2,
  author = {Writer, William},
  title  = {Second Bibliography: Category 2},
  date   = {2010},
}
@book{book4,
  author = {Poetaster, Paula},
  title  = {Second Bibliography Again: Category B},
  date   = {1767},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname-1.bib}
\addbibresource{\jobname-2.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{book1,book2,book3,book4}
\newrefcontext[labelprefix=R]
\printbibliography[keyword=file1]
\newrefcontext[labelprefix=O]
\printbibliography[keyword=file2, title=Other references]
\end{document}
```

[image: "[R1, O2, R2, O1]//References//[R1] Anne Onymous. First Bibliography: Category 1. 2000.//[R2] Sarah Scribbler. First Bibliography Again: Category A and B. 1899.//References//[O1] Paula Poetaster. Second Bibliography Again: Category B. 1767.//[O2] William Writer. Second Bibliography: Category 2. 2010." The citation labels starting with "O" are coloured blue, the others are black.]

*edit* How embarassing! I completely forgot to colour the citations according to their file/keyword. That is fixed now. Sorry!

Comment: Thanks a lot...but, when I would like to merge the example with my Elsevier article, by using \documentclass[5p,preprint,10pt,authoryear]{elsarticle} \usepackage{ecrc}. It is giving me an error of "! Package biblatex Error: Incompatible package 'natbib'."   Please guide me how can I resolve it?

Comment: @MuhammadHammad Sorry, `elsarticle` is completely incompatible with `biblatex`, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/468152/35864. There are theoretically ways to hack around that (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/321989/35864), but I'm pretty sure Elsevier will not like that.