# How to create two separate bibliographies in the same document?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, natbib

At the end of my paper I would like to create two separated lists of references, since I prefer to **distinguish** usual **book references** from the **references of pictures** I included.

I already tried several ways, but mostly they are only appropriate for bibliographies in certain sections.

#### Current situation:

I have two different files

- *thesis.bib* contains the book and journal references I used for my text
- *figures.bib* contains the references, where I found the images used in the paper

At the moment I get the "Bibliography" by writing

```
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibpunct{[}{]}{,}{a}{}{;}
```

at the beginning of my document and

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\numberline{}Bibliography}
\bibliographystyle{alphadin}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{thesis}
```

at the end of it. However, if I want to include a "References of Figures" the same way, it just adds another copy of the previously listed "Bibliography".

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\numberline{}References of Figures}
\bibliographystyle{alphadin}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{figures}
```

So how can I add the list of "References of Figures" after the normal bibliography?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you consider using `biblatex`? It uses the notion  of `bibliography by categories` to filter what is printed.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You tagged your question with `biblatex`. The `biblatex` package is completely incompatible with `natbib`. Was the inclusion of the tag an oversight or are you open to switch to `biblatex`? Please clarify your question accordingly (i.e. remove the `biblatex` tag if you don't want to switch, or add a short statement that you would consider switching to `biblatex`). Note that switching to `biblatex` would mean that you can not continue using the `alphadin` style. ...

Comment: ... If you want to stick with `natbib`, you may want to look into https://ctan.org/pkg/bibtopic, https://ctan.org/pkg/multibib, https://www.ctan.org/pkg/multibbl, https://www.ctan.org/pkg/splitbib

Comment: thanks for your answers. I wasn't aware of this incompatibility and would also consider using biblatex, if it provides a convenient solution for the problem.

I guess first I will also look for possible solutions in the provided links.

Comment: A `biblatex` solution will in all likeliness be slightly simpler than the other solution, but that comes at a cost of switching your entire bibliography set-up from `natbib` to `biblatex` with Biber. (Background [natbib vs biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701/35864).) You will not be able to use `alphadin` and will have to find another style that you like. If you find no style that you like, you will have to go into the business of customising `biblatex` - while that is easier than customising BibTeX it is still work.

Comment: The `biblatex` solution for you current set-up is at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35279/35864. You can add a `keyword` to your entries depending on which file they came from. Then you can filter your bibliographies with `\printbibliography[notkeyword=figures,title={Real bibliography}]` and `\printbibliography[keyword=figures, title={}References of figures}]`

Comment: Thank you! Meanwhile I could solve the problem with multibib.

Comment: Please write down an answer and accept it if you could solve your problem (you have to wait a certain time to be able to accept your self-answers, but that is fine). That helps future visitors with the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could solve my problem with multibib.
At the end I had two different bibliograhies:

- Bibliography (which contained all referces I used in my text)
- References of Figures (refers to figures)

This is how it is done:

```
\usepackage[resetlabels,labeled]{multibib}
\newcites{Fig}{References of Figures}


\begin{document}

\bibliographystyleFig{alpha}
\bibliographyFig{figures}

\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{thesis}

\end{document}
```

In the document write

```
\cite{---}
```

to cite books, articles etc. for the text, and

```
\citeFig{---}
```

in order to create references to figures.