# with biber, how to declare that all citations in a given file are of a given category?

Tags: biblatex, biber

I am using `biblatex` with Biber. I am using categories to separate citations that belong to different types and to produce different bibliographies accordingly.
Let's say I have `a.bib` file that contains bib records (let's say with labels `a1`, a2, ...) that all belong to a category `c1`, and a `b.bib` file that contains bib records (labels `b1`, `b2`, ...) that all belong to category `c2`.
Currently, I write something like this:

```
\usepackage[citestyle=numeric-comp,backend=biber,defernumbers=true]{biblatex}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{c1}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{c2}
\addtocategory{c1}{a1,a2,...}
\addtocategory{c2}{b1,b2,...}
\addbibresource{a.bib}
\addbibresource{b.bib}
```

Is there an easy way to say: "all bib records in `a.bib` belong to `c1`, without listing them all?"

Answer (score 6):

`biblatex` offers two main solutions to the task of splitting/categorising entries into arbitrary subsets

1. bibliography categories and
2. keywords.

Bibliography categories work on the fly on the document side. You declare categories with `\DeclareBibliographyCategory` and add entries to categories with `\addtocategory` in your document. Categories are useful for ad-hoc classification and grouping that may vary from document to document. One great example of categories is [How to split bibliography into "works cited" and "works not cited"?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6967/35864), where categories are used to split the bibliography in cited works and those added with `\nocite`.

Keywords on the other hand are added to the `.bib` file in the `keywords` field. They require no further set-up in the document and can be used directly to filter bibliographies with `keyword=<keyword>` or for general purpose tests with `\ifkeyword{<keyword>}{<true>}{<false>}`. Since keywords come from the `.bib` file, they are usually tied to a specific *entry* and not to a *document*.

For the most part, categories and keywords can be used in a similar fashion once they are known/defined.

---

When Biber/BibTeX has processed your `.bib` file and passes the data on to `biblatex` in the `.bbl` there is no information about the data source of each entry. That makes it extremely hard to generate categories from `.bib` files, since the relevant data is not available any more.

There is, however, a trick to let Biber add different *keywords* for each `.bib` file as shown in [biblatex: multiple bibliographies categorised by different .bib files](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35279/35864).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \perdatasource{\jobname-primary.bib}
      \step[fieldset=keywords, fieldvalue={, primary}, append]
    }
    \map{
      \perdatasource{\jobname-secondary.bib}
      \step[fieldset=keywords, fieldvalue={, secondary}, append]
    }
  }
}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname-primary.bib}
@BOOK{hectic,
  AUTHOR    = {Henry Hectic},
  TITLE     = {How Horticulturalists Howl},
  PUBLISHER = {Honorary Books: Henage},
  YEAR      = {2000}
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname-secondary.bib}
@BOOK{flutter,
  AUTHOR    = {Frederick Flutter},
  TITLE     = {Fraternising with Flowers},
  PUBLISHER = {Frippery Pamphlets: Folkestone},
  YEAR      = {1995}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname-primary.bib}
\addbibresource{\jobname-secondary.bib}

\begin{document}
Some citations: \cite{hectic}, \cite{flutter}.
\printbibliography[title=Primary Sources, keyword=primary]
\printbibliography[title=Secondary Sources, keyword=secondary]
\end{document}
```

If you insist on *categories*, this can be used as a roundabout way to produce categories in the end as follows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \perdatasource{\jobname-primary.bib}
      \step[fieldset=keywords, fieldvalue={, primary}, append]
    }
    \map{
      \perdatasource{\jobname-secondary.bib}
      \step[fieldset=keywords, fieldvalue={, secondary}, append]
    }
  }
}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{primary}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{secondary}

\AtDataInput{%
  \ifkeyword{primary}
    {\addtocategory{primary}{\thefield{entrykey}}}
    {}%
  \ifkeyword{secondary}
    {\addtocategory{secondary}{\thefield{entrykey}}}
    {}%    
}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname-primary.bib}
@BOOK{hectic,
  AUTHOR    = {Henry Hectic},
  TITLE     = {How Horticulturalists Howl},
  PUBLISHER = {Honorary Books: Henage},
  YEAR      = {2000}
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname-secondary.bib}
@BOOK{flutter,
  AUTHOR    = {Frederick Flutter},
  TITLE     = {Fraternising with Flowers},
  PUBLISHER = {Frippery Pamphlets: Folkestone},
  YEAR      = {1995}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname-primary.bib}
\addbibresource{\jobname-secondary.bib}

\begin{document}
Some citations: \cite{hectic}, \cite{flutter}.
\printbibliography[title=Primary Sources, category=primary]
\printbibliography[title=Secondary Sources, category=secondary]
\end{document}
```

But I doubt that that is going to provide a great advantage.