# Automatically split sources list into bibliography and references

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibtex, biber

I am currently reading up on how to properly format used resources. Doing so I found out it is customary to distinguish between references and bibliography, the former being the list of sources actually *referenced* in the text, like

*This was finding was made by Smith (2008)*

and the latter being a list of materials used by the author that are not directly referenced in the text.

I would like to achieve this format with biblatex. Consider the following example

**main.tex:**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber, bibencoding=utf8, style=apa, natbib=true]{biblatex}

\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}

\addbibresource{sample.bib}

\begin{document}

A discussion of the subject can be found in \citet{Smith08}.
\nocite{Baker10}

\printbibliography[]

\end{document}
```

**sample.bib:**

```
@book{Smith08,
    author = {Smith, E.},
    year = {2008},
    title = {The other book},
}

@book{Baker10,
    author = {Baker, M.},
    year = {2010},
    title = {The book},
}
```

I would like the sources list generated to look like this, as Baker (2010) was not directly referenced but Smith (2008) was:

**Bibliography**

Baker, M. (2010). *The book.*

**References**

Smith, E. (2008). *The other book.*

I suspect this can be done with `\DeclareBibliographyCategory` somehow, but I can't figure out how.

But maybe there is even a better way as this seems like a standard format.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6967/35864 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35279/35864

Comment: With a recent version of `biblatex` (>= 3.8) and `biblatex-apa` (>= 7.5) [both released around November 2017; Overleaf has an older version], you don't need the `\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can split your bibliography and then append keywords to identify different bibliography entries. A MWE:

```
    \documentclass{article}

    \usepackage[american]{babel}
    \usepackage[backend=biber, bibencoding=utf8, style=apa, natbib=true]{biblatex}

    \DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}


    \usepackage{filecontents}

    \begin{filecontents}{biblatextest1.bib}
    @book{Baker10,
        author = {Baker, M.},
        year = {2010},
        title = {The book},
    }
    \end{filecontents}
    %
    \begin{filecontents}{biblatextest2.bib}
    @book{Smith08,
        author = {Smith, E.},
        year = {2008},
        title = {The other book},
    }
    \end{filecontents}

    \addbibresource{biblatextest1.bib}
    \addbibresource{biblatextest2.bib}

    %Append keywords to identify different bibliography entries.
    \DeclareSourcemap{
        \maps[datatype=bibtex, overwrite]{
            \map{
                \perdatasource{biblatextest1.bib}
                \step[fieldset=KEYWORDS, fieldvalue=primary, append]
            }
            \map{
                \perdatasource{biblatextest2.bib}
                \step[fieldset=KEYWORDS, fieldvalue=secondary, append]
            }
        }
    }
    \begin{document}

    A discussion of the subject can be found in \cite{Smith08}.
    \nocite{Baker10}

    \printbibliography[title=Bibliography, keyword=primary]
    \printbibliography[title=References, keyword=secondary]

    \end{document}
```

[image]

With only a `bib` source declaring a category:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber, bibencoding=utf8, style=apa, natbib=true]{biblatex}

\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}



\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{biblatextest.bib}
@book{Baker10,
    author = {Baker, M.},
    year = {2010},
    title = {The book},
}
@book{Smith08,
    author = {Smith, E.},
    year = {2008},
    title = {The other book},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{biblatextest.bib}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{cited}
\AtEveryCitekey{\addtocategory{cited}{\thefield{entrykey}}}


\begin{document}

A discussion of the subject can be found in \cite{Smith08}.
\nocite{Baker10}

\printbibliography[title=Bibliography,notcategory=cited]
\printbibliography[title=References,category=cited]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ok, cool. But there is no better way? This looks like a lot of hassle with many sources. I imagined there might be a solution based on whether the source was called with a variant of `\cite` versus `\nocite`, as `\cite` means the source was referenced and `\nocite` means it was not referenced.

Comment: @ lo tolmencre, see my edited answer

Comment: Great, exactly what I had in mind. Thanks!

Comment: I've just implemented this (the first part of your answer) in my document; thank you for this solution. Something I've noticed is that citations in the `.bib` file that include the `keywords` term do not display in the printed bibliography list; it appears the use of keywords as filtering is incompatible with the `keywords` metadata term - not that I've ever needed that term anyway.