# Separate reference and bibliography

Tags: biblatex

I am trying to separate the reference and the bibliography using biblatex, and I am trying to achieve it by having two separate bib files, but I am not quite sure how should I get on with it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{main.bib}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

the main text

\printbibliograph
\end{document}
```

Comment: What is the difference between references and the bibliography for your purposes? Are the references the works cited in the document and the bibliography is a kind of 'further reading' section? In that case https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6967/35864 is more elegant than a solution with different `.bib` files. If references and bibliography differ in another way, you could use `keywords` (if the difference is inherent to the `.bib` entries) or categories (if the difference is linked to the specific document you write).

Comment: If you are absolutely committed to a solution using two different `.bib` files, you'd probably go via automatically added `keywords`: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35279/35864

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe an own `refsection` for the bibliography can help?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}


\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{main.bib}
@article{aksin,
  author       = {Aks{\i}n, {\"O}zge and T{\"u}rkmen, Hayati and Artok, Levent
                  and {\c{C}}etinkaya, Bekir and Ni, Chaoying and
                  B{\"u}y{\"u}kg{\"u}ng{\"o}r, Orhan and {\"O}zkal, Erhan},
  title        = {Effect of immobilization on catalytic characteristics of
                  saturated {Pd-N}-heterocyclic carbenes in {Mizoroki-Heck}
                  reactions},
  journaltitle = jomch,
  date         = 2006,
  volume       = 691,
  number       = 13,
  pages        = {3027-3036},
  indextitle   = {Effect of immobilization on catalytic characteristics},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{bibliography.bib}
@article{angenendt,
  author       = {Angenendt, Arnold},
  title        = {In Honore Salvatoris~-- Vom Sinn und Unsinn der
                  Patrozinienkunde},
  journaltitle = {Revue d'Histoire Eccl{\'e}siastique},
  date         = 2002,
  volume       = 97,
  pages        = {431--456, 791--823},
  langid       = {german},
  indextitle   = {In Honore Salvatoris},
  shorttitle   = {In Honore Salvatoris},
  annotation   = {A German article in a French journal. Apart from that, a
                  typical \texttt{article} entry. Note the \texttt{indextitle}
                  field},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource[label=main]{main.bib}
\addbibresource[label=bibliography]{bibliography.bib}

\begin{document}

the main text \cite{aksin}
\printbibliography

\begin{refsection}[bibliography]
\nocite{*}\printbibliography[title=Bibliography]
\end{refsection}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!