# Separate bibliography files for separate bibliographies

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

For a research project, I would like to create a literature list that organizes a relatively large number of references into different categories, using `biblatex`. I would like to do this by having multiple `.bib` files, and then be capable of printing all references in such a file with a single command, without having to cite them first.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35279/35864 + `\nocite{*}` should get you started. If that does not work, please describe in more details what you tried (post an example document and example `.bib` files) and explain how it did not work for you.

Comment: Did the link help you? Or did it not do what you hoped to achieve?

Comment: Oh yes, sorry for not responding. Yes indeed, it did help. I didn't get around to try the xml file, but that should be routine. You can link this as a double, if you like.

Comment: You don't need to use the `.bcf`/XML thing, the code for the document preamble (of your `.tex` file) is at the end of the answer, usually that is a bit easier to manage.