# Biblatex Works Cited + Bibliography

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing

I have two files,

1. bib.bib
2. ref.bib

I cite articles from ref.bib with a \cite{} command and I'd like these citations (and only these citations which have been called from a \cite{} command) printed in a "works cited" or "references" section.

bib.bib has works that I've consulted at various points in writing the text and I'd like the entire contents of this file printed to a "bibliography" section.

I'm using biblatex

Please advise

Comment: Does this answer help? https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35779/87678

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are not planning on citing anything from `bib.bib`, it should be enough to define a labelled `refsection` with a `\nocite{*}`.

Since `refsection`s are kept completely separate from each other and labelled `refsection`s only take the `.bib` files from their label, the `\nocite{*}` will only apply to entries from `bib.bib`.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{ref.bib}
@article{sigfridsson,
  author       = {Sigfridsson, Emma and Ryde, Ulf},
  title        = {Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the
                  electrostatic potential and moments},
  journaltitle = {Journal of Computational Chemistry},
  date         = 1998,
  volume       = 19,
  number       = 4,
  pages        = {377-395},
  doi          = {10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P},
}
@article{herrmann,
  author       = {Herrmann, Wolfgang A. and {\"O}fele, Karl and Schneider,
                  Sabine K.  and Herdtweck, Eberhardt and Hoffmann, Stephan D.},
  title        = {A carbocyclic carbene as an efficient catalyst ligand for {C--C}
                  coupling reactions},
  journaltitle = {Angew.~Chem. Int.~Ed.},
  date         = 2006,
  volume       = 45,
  number       = 23,
  pages        = {3859-3862},
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{bib.bib}
@book{worman,
  author       = {Worman, Nancy},
  title        = {The Cast of Character},
  date         = 2002,
  publisher    = {University of Texas Press},
  location     = {Austin},
}
@book{nussbaum,
  author       = {Nussbaum, Martha},
  title        = {Aristotle's \mkbibquote{De Motu Animalium}},
  date         = 1978,
  publisher    = {Princeton University Press},
  location     = {Princeton},
  keywords     = {secondary},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{bib.bib}
\addbibresource{ref.bib}


\begin{document}
Lorem \cite{sigfridsson}
\printbibliography

\begin{refsection}[bib.bib]
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[title=Bibliography]
\end{refsection}
\end{document}
```

[image: References with one entry (sigfridsson) and bibliography with two entries (nussbaum, worman).]