# renewcommand in a newcommand

Tags: macros, expansion

I have a command `\putansline{1}{2}` that inserts `1` line of dots and prints the total score as `[2]`. I want to define a new command that if issued, will redefine this command so that it prints only the score. Here's what I have for this new command:

```
\newcommand{\hideanslines}{%
  \renewcommand{\putansline}[2]{[#2]}
}%
```

I get an `illegal parameter number` error for this new command though. How can I define this new command `hideanslines` so that after I issue it, putansline can only print the points and not the lines?

Comment: The nested-ness of a macro definition increases the number of `#`'s by a factor of 2. See the following UK TeX FAQ entries: [Illegal parameter number in definition](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=errparnum), followed by [Defining LaTeX commands within other commands](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=ltxhash) (for a LaTeX reference) and [Defining macros within macros](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=hash) (for a TeX reference).

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use two `#`'s.

```
\newcommand{\hideanslines}{%
  \renewcommand{\putansline}[2]{[##2]}%
}
```