# Why do paramaters of \renewcommand need to double up the # within a \foreach

Tags: macros, foreach

### Introduction:

When you use `\renewcommand` within another macro or environment, one needs to double up the `##` to access the parameters of the inner macro.  This serves as a way to distinguish the inner macros `##1` with the outer macros `#1` (even if the outer macro does not have any parameters, it provides for error checking). For example:

```
\newcommand*{\OuterCommand}{%
    \renewcommand*{\SomeCommand}[1]{\color{red}##1}%
    ....
}%
```

The references below provide more details on this.

### Issue:

It appears that the same doubling up of the `#` is needed within a `\foreach` loop as illustrated in the MWE below.

This took me quite some time to figure this out as the error message that the MWE below gives is:

> Illegal parameter number in definition of \pgffor@body

This was within a very deeply nesting of `\foreach` loops, so I was sure the problem was that I was nesting the `\foreach` too deeply.  Surprisingly, if you skip past the error, the output is still correct, so this made it even harder to locate the problem.

### Questions:

- Since the `\foreach` does not have parameters like `#1` (as `\newcommand` does), why is it necessary to double up the `#` within a definition within a `\foreach`?
- How is that the output is still correct, if you simply ignore the error and hit return to continue processing?

### References:

- [renewcommand in a newcommand](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39339/renewcommand-in-a-newcommand).
- [Defining LaTeX commands within other commands](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-ltxhash).
- [Nesting command definitions more than two levels](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51819/nesting-command-definitions-more-than-two-levels/).

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\newcommand*{\MyList}{A,B,C}%
\newcommand{\SomeCommand}[1]{#1}%

\begin{document}
\foreach \x in \MyList {%
    \renewcommand*{\SomeCommand}[1]{\color{red}#1}%  Using ## here eliminates the error.
    \par\SomeCommand{\x}%
}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Actually you don't need to use `##1` "to access the parameters of the inner macro" it is simply that you need to use `##` to enter `#`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Interesting way to look at it. Never thought if `#` as escaping the `#`. But, then how do you explain that you need 4 for the next level? :-)

Comment: I'll add some notes to the answer, code formatting in comments is rubbish

Comment: Related Question: [How to insert a # via \immediate\write18 within a macro](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/245622/how-to-insert-a-via-immediate-write18-within-a-macro).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Internally the definition of foreach will be saving the body of the loop in a macro so it is like (if looping over `a,b,...` )

```
\def\body{%
\renewcommand*{\SomeCommand}[1]{\color{red}#1}%  Using ## here eliminates the error.
    \par\SomeCommand{\x}%
}%
}
\def\x{a}\body
\def\x{b}\body
...
```

That initial `\def` (or `\newcommand` if you prefer) will require a `#` in the body to be entered as `##`. As shown above you would get an error on `#1` as `\body` doesn't take parameters it would have to be entered, as you found, as `##1`.

It is possible to define loops in such a way not to require this (for example it could use a token register rather than a macro for saving the body) but that is apparently not the case here.

---

Note that the need to double `#` is unrelated to the fact that there is an inner macro definition. It is not that inner macros require `##1` to refer to the first parameter, it is simply that the inner macro definition requires the two tokens `#` and `1` to refer to the first parameter and to get a `#` into a macro body you need `##`. To see this consider a definition that doesn't have `##1`.

You can go

```
\let\hash=#
```

and `\hash` will be let to `#` but you can not define a macro as

```
\def\definehash{\let\hash=#}
```

as that generates

```
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \definehash.
```

You need `##` to refer to a literal `#` in a macro definition. So it needs to be

```
\def\definehash{\let\hash=##}
```

You ask in comments why it needs four `#` for a double nested definition. Again it is nothing special about the inner definitions, they never "see" `##1` by the time they are evaluated they just see a single `#`. If you tried to define

```
\def\ddefinehash{\def\definehash{\let\hash=##}}
```

The definition would proceed without error but then if you try to execute `\ddefinehash` you find that it just has a *single* `#` in its definition and so you get the error as before:

```
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \definehash.
<to be read again> 
                   }
l.12 \ddefinehash
```

So you need to get *two* `#` into the definition of `\definehash` and each of those has to be entered as `##` so you end up with

```
\def\ddefinehash{\def\definehash{\let\hash=####}}
```

---

Putting it all together:

```
{
\let\hash=#
}

{
\def\definehash{\let\hash=##}
}

{
\def\ddefinehash{\def\definehash{\let\hash=####}}
\ddefinehash
\definehash

\show\ddefinehash
\show\definehash
\show\hash
}

\bye
```

---

```
> \ddefinehash=macro:
->\def \definehash {\let \hash =####}.
l.15 \show\ddefinehash

? 
> \definehash=macro:
->\let \hash =##.
l.16 \show\definehash

? 
> \hash=macro parameter character #.
l.17 \show\hash

? 
 )
No pages of output.
```