# Metacommand for commands that dynamically select a parameter?

Tags: macros, tex-core, expansion

## Original question

I would like to create a metacommand for creating new projection commands.  Specifically, `\newproj{\cmd}{<n>}{<m>}` should create `\cmd` as a new command of `<n>` (mandatory) arguments that always expands to the `<m>`th argument.

For example, if we have `\newproj{\fst}{2}{1}` and `\newproj{\snd}{2}{2}`, then `\fst{x}{y}` should expand to `x` whereas `\snd{x}{y}` should expand to `y`.

Here is my attempt at this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*{\newproj}[3]{%
  \newcommand*#1[#2]{%
    \expandafter#\expandafter##3%
  }%
}

\newproj{\fst}{2}{1}
\newproj{\snd}{2}{2}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\verb^\fst{x}{y}^:& \fst{x}{y} \\
\verb^\snd{x}{y}^:& \snd{x}{y}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, this gives the error "Illegal parameter number in definition of `\newproj`.
`<to be read again> \expandafter`"  How can I use a parameter as a function of some integer or metaparameter?

## Extended question: indirection via a macro

A.Ellett and Hendrik Vogt suggest using `\newcommand*#1[#2]{###3}` because `##` expands to `#`.  This works perfectly if a positive integer is passed as `#3` to `\newproj`!  However, suppose that I pass a macro to `\newproj` as `#3`.  How can I use expansion of a macro to dynamically select a parameter?

For example, the following should produce the correct results.  However, it gives the error "Illegal parameter number in definition of `\fst`.  `<to be read again> \i`".

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*{\newproj}[3]{%
  \newcommand*#1[#2]{%
    \expandafter###3%
  }%
}

\def\i{1}
\newproj{\fst}{2}{\i}
\newproj{\snd}{2}{2}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\verb^\fst{x}{y}^:& \fst{x}{y} \\
\verb^\snd{x}{y}^:& \snd{x}{y}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just omit the `\expandafter`s: `\newcommand*{\newproj}[3]{\newcommand*#1[#2]{###3}}` does the job.

Comment: @HendrikVogt Thanks; it works great!  I've extended the question slightly to include the case where a macro is used to select the parameter.  Do you have any ideas for that case?

Comment: Consider doing this with a loop: `\foreach \x/\y/\z in {fst/2/\i,snd/2/2}{<do something>}`.

Comment: @AhmedMusa How does the loop help with defining `\newproj`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

You just want to fully expand both arguments using `\number` to get their decimal expansion, while avoiding expanding everything else (for which a toks register is useful)

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*{\newproj}[3]{%
  \toks0{\newcommand*#1}%
  \edef\tmp{\the\toks0[\number#2]{####\number#3}}%
\tmp
  }

\def\i{1}
\newproj{\fst}{2}{\i}
\newproj{\snd}{2}{2}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\verb^\fst{x}{y}^:& \fst{x}{y} \\
\verb^\snd{x}{y}^:& \snd{x}{y}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Always something to learn from your answers.  :)

Comment: Not sure I understand.  Why doesn't something like `\newcommand*{\newproj}[3]{\newcommand*#1[#2]{\expandafter##\number#3}}` work?

Comment: @HenryDeYoung Because with `\newproj{\fst}{2}{1}` you would be doing `\newcommand*\fst[2]{\expandafter#\number1}` which is illegal.

Comment: @egreg So, even though `##` can be dealt with at expansion time, the other `#`s (such as `#\number`) must be dealt with at definition time (and therefore can't be postponed using `\expandafter`).  Is that correct?

Comment: I think you have that backwards `#` (and only `#`) is handled specially at the point of definition. The rest of the tokens in the definition are just saved and then processed once the macro is expanded. # must be followed by # or a digit so #\number is a syntax error and prevents the definition at all.

Comment: @HenryDeYoung see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71632/why-do-paramaters-of-renewcommand-need-to-double-up-the-within-a-foreach/71633#71633

Comment: Thanks for the link; that was very helpful.  I think I understand now.  `\newproj{\fst}{2}{\i}` becomes `\toks0{\newcommand*\fst} \edef\tmp{\the\toks0[\number2]{##\number\i}} \tmp`.  Next, the `\edef` is processed, but `##` is replaced with a literal `#` before the full expansion occurs.  All told, the effect is the same as writing `\def\tmp{\newcommand*\fst[2]{#1}}`.  Importantly, expansion never affects `#` because `#` is unexpandable.  Is that right?

Comment: You were doing well until the last line:-) # isn't expandable or unexpandable. If met out of a def it's a syntax error, it's behaviour in edef and def is the same (perhaps that's what you meant) in either case the following token must be # or a digit in the former case the replacement text of the macro geta s (single) # token, in the later case it gets a parameter marker which is filled with teh actual parameter when the macro is expanded.

Comment: Ugh, sorry; last question, I promise.  This also seems to work without `\number`.  What is the `\number` there for?  Catcodes?

Comment: no \number is needed to expand \i to 1 and would be needed for #2 if you used a macro in the other argument. ah well I lied as I ended up using \edef \i expands anyway but number expands count registers \count@ or \value{equation} or whatever.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a start at something

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\newproj}[3]{%
    \expandafter\newcommand\csname #1\expandafter\endcsname[#2]{###3}
}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

Hello

\newproj{helloworldapplesauce}{4}{3}

\helloworldapplesauce{a}{b}{c}{d}
\end{document}
```

Alternatively you might try to do (following the advice of @HendrikVogt )

```
\newcommand{\newproj}[3]{\newcommand{#1}[#2]{###3}}
```

should also do the trick

Regardless of the approach, you'll probably want to make sure that the values passed in the parameters are numbers and that whatever is passed in the third argument defining the function is no larger than the second.

Comment: Thanks; this works, but I'd like to understand why.  I would have thought that `###3` would refer to the third argument of a doubly nested command.

Comment: In David Salomon's *The Advanced TeXbook* page 126, he explains that `###1` is the same as `## #1` where the `##` expands to `#`.  He references pg 203 of Knuth where it is explained a bit further.

Comment: Thanks; it works great! I've extended the question slightly to include the case where a macro is used to select the parameter. Do you have any ideas for that case?

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{catoptions}
\makeatletter
% \generateparams is not any costlier than using \newcommand:
\new@def*\generateparams#1#2{%
  \ifnum#1<\numexpr#2+1####\number#1%
    \expandafter\generateparams
    \expandafter{\number\numexpr#1+1\expandafter}%
    \expandafter{\number#2\expandafter}%
  \fi
}
\robust@def*\newproj#1#2#3{%
  \@ifdefinable#1\relax
  \cptexpanded{\def\noexpand#1\generateparams1{#2}{#####3}}%
}

% Examples of \newproj:
\def\one{1}
\newproj{\fst}{2}{\one}
\newproj{\snd}{2}{2}

% Using a loop to avoid repeating \newproj for every new definition:
\robust@def*\NewProj#1{%
  \cptforeach \x/\y/\z \in#1\do{%
    \cptexpandsecond\newproj{\noexpandcsn{\x}{\y}{\z}}%
  }%
}

% Examples of \NewProj:
\NewProj{fstb/2/\one, sndb/2/2}

\makeatother

% Let us print the examples:
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\verb^\fst{x}{y}^:& \fst{x}{y} \\
\verb^\snd{x}{y}^:& \snd{x}{y} \\
\verb^\fstb{x}{y}^:& \fstb{x}{y} \\
\verb^\sndb{x}{y}^:& \sndb{x}{y}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With `expl3` one can define a temporary macro and set the desired one to be equal to it. Nothing is left behind, because we are doing it in a group and exploit that `\cs_new_eq:NN` (here in the `\cs_new_eq:Nc` variant) does a global definition.

I use `\prg_replicate:nn` to build the desired number of arguments.

Possible variation: if a non-long macro is desired, use `\cs_set_nopar:cx` instead of `\cs_set:cx`.

Both arguments can be macros or integer variables.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\newproj}{mmm}
 {% #1 is the name of a command
  % #2 is the number of arguments
  % #3 is the argument to choose
  \group_begin:
  \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl { __deyoung_temp: \prg_replicate:nn { #2 } { n } }
  \cs_set:cx { \l_tmpa_tl } { ## \int_eval:n { #3 } }
  \cs_new_eq:Nc #1 { \l_tmpa_tl }
  \group_end:
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand\idx{1} \newcounter{baz} \setcounter{baz}{2}
\newproj{\fst}{2}{\idx}
\newproj{\snd}{2}{\value{baz}}

\begin{document}

\verb^\fst{x}{y}^: \fst{x}{y}

\verb^\snd{x}{y}^: \snd{x}{y}

Is it expandable? \edef\test{\fst{x}{y}}
\texttt{\meaning\test}

\newproj{\foo}{9}{4}\texttt{\meaning\foo}

\end{document}
```

[image]