# Using before as a Global setting in enumitem

Tags: enumitem, description, grouping

I am working on a small project and am using the enumitem package reasons for beyond this example. I read the docs and managed to produce this example. Currently, I am using the before argument on the \begin{description} (uncomment part of line 6).

To facilitate reuse I would like to move it into the global settings for description the description environment (line 4). However, it appears to be beyond my understanding.

Thanks for the help

```
\documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{enumitem}

  %\setlist[description]{before={\renewcommand{\makelabel}[1]{\textit{##1}: }}} % Illegal parameter number in definition of \enit@@description.
  \begin{document}
    \begin{description}%[before={\renewcommand{\makelabel}[1]{\textit{##1}: }}]
      \item[square]{a four-sided polygon is a square if and only if all sides are equal and its vertex angles are all right angles.}
    \end{description}
  \end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something here, but why don't you just use `\setlist[description]{font=\normalfont\itshape}` rather than using the `before` code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your goal is simply to change the formatting of the description label, then you shouldn't be using the `before` argument at all, but instead just specifying the format for the label. If you're just changing font properties you can use the `font` argument (e.g. `font=\normalfont\itshape`) If you want to add material to the label (as you state in the comment), the best way to do that is to make a command to add the colon (or do any other formatting you want) and use that command as the last  in the `format` argument.  There should generally be very little need for the `before` argument with respect to formatting the parts of the list itself.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newcommand\addcolon[1]{#1:}
\setlist[description]{format=\normalfont\itshape\addcolon}.
\begin{document}
  \begin{description}
    \item[square]{a four-sided polygon is a square if and only if all sides are
     equal and its vertex angles are all right angles.}
  \end{description}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That is noted, but I am also adding characters after the label (colon in the example).

Comment: I've added code to do that, without using `before`.

Answer (score 2):

The package apparently passes that argument through three levels of macro definition so you need

```
\documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{enumitem}

  \setlist[description]{before={\renewcommand{\makelabel}[1]{\textit{########1}: }}} % Illegal parameter number in definition of \enit@@description.
  \begin{document}
    \begin{description}%[before={\renewcommand{\makelabel}[1]{\textit{##1}: }}]
      \item[square]{a four-sided polygon is a square if and only if all sides are equal and its vertex angles are all right angles.}
      \item[square]{a four-sided polygon is a square if and only if all sides are equal and its vertex angles are all right angles.}
    \end{description}
  \end{document}
```

Comment: Wow! Is there a good way to find that out other than just reading the code or guessing?

Comment: @Raisdead In this case, I just doubled them till it worked (it helps to know that that process will terminate:-) You could read the code and work it out, or the package could have been written not to require doubling `#`.

Comment: @Raisdead  See [Why do paramaters of \renewcommand need to double up the # within a \foreach](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/71632) for some nice discussion of this. (Also by David).

Comment: @AlanMunn Thanks for that reference. I'll be sure to read it thoroughly.