# Nested definitions

Tags: macros, parameters

I have the impression that if one defines a macro inside the definition of another one, then `#1` and so on indicate the outer macro's arguments, while `##1` indicates those of the inner one. Is that right? Could one theoretically go furher, i.e. define a macro inside the definition of a macro defines inside the definition of a third one, thus using `###1` for the innermost macro's argument? If so, how many levels of nesting would be allowed?

Comment: Not *quite*: with each nesting level you have to double the number of `#`. So for the third level: `####1`, for the fourth `########1` and so on

Comment: The comment and the question linked in the duplicate tag leave me with just one last question: Is there a limit to the nunber of nested definitions or could one give definitions with a theoretically unkimited nesting number?

Comment: Not that I would know. I never needed more than three levels

Comment: @MickG you will use up input stack for nested definitions (whether or not you use `###`) the limit is setable in `texmf.cnf` and defaults to 5000 in texlive 2014

Comment: see also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71632/why-do-paramaters-of-renewcommand-need-to-double-up-the-within-a-foreach/71633#71633