# How to insert a # via \immediate\write18 within a macro

Tags: symbols, shell-escape, scripts

It seems that using

```
\immediate\write18{echo "\string#!/bin/bash (version 1)"  > \jobname.command}%
```

*outside* of a `\newcommand` works great. However, I want to invoke within a `\newcommand`:

```
\newcommand{\CreateBashScript}{%
   \immediate\write18{echo "\string#!/bin/bash (version 2)"  > \jobname.command}%
}%
```

but this has an issue with the `#` (hash / pound symbol).

### Notes:

- To reproduce the problem you need to uncomment the line in the definition of `\CreateBashScript`.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\immediate\write18{echo "\string#!/bin/bash (version 1)"  > \jobname.command}%

\newcommand{\CreateBashScript}{%
%    \immediate\write18{echo "\string#!/bin/bash (version 2)"  > \jobname.command}%
}%

\begin{document}
    \CreateBashScript
\end{document}
```

Comment: It's the usual 'you need to double `#` symbols inside macro definitions' (see _e.g._ http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42463/)

Comment: @JosephWright: Yep that works great. Thanks. I though that since I was using `\string` the double `##` issue did not occur to me. Also, even though it is the same answer as the linked question, in this case I am _not_ trying to define a macro via a macro which is where the usual doubling of the `#` comes up. Or at least that was my understanding.

Comment: see this related question somebody once asked http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71632/why-do-paramaters-of-renewcommand-need-to-double-up-the-within-a-foreach/71633#71633 :-)

Comment: @PeterGrill the `\string` isn't executed while the command is being defined, and you need `##` to put a `#` into the replacement text.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Wow, that is a brilliant question you linked to, oh and the answer is good too :-).

Comment: `\edef\writehash{\string#}` in the preamble and `\writehash` where you want to print a hash mark.

Comment: @egreg: Excellent solution. With that I don't need to do anything different within a macro. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since macros are expanded in a `\write`, I'd have

```
\edef\shebang{\string#!/bin/bash}
```

in the preamble so that you can use

```
\newcommand{\CreateBashScript}{%
    \immediate\write18{echo "\shebang" > \jobname.command}%
}
```

in the command.

As told in the comment, you could also double the `#` in the replacement text

```
\newcommand{\CreateBashScript}{%
    \immediate\write18{echo "\string##!/bin/bash"  > \jobname.command}%
}
```

but I believe that `\shebang` is clearer.

Answer (score 2):

I fought with this problem for two days now and came across this great answer a thousand times before I understood its relevance. Therefore I attempt to reformulate it, stripped to its essence:

If you want to write out a literal # into some file, you can do something like

```
\newcommand{\writeouthash}{%
  \immediate\write\myfile{\string##}%
}
```