# Why must parameters for inner macro definitions double each #?

Tags: macros, tex-core

Or "When would an expression like `###1` be useful?"

In macro programming, it's a well-known rule that you need to double your parameter identifiers with each successive layer:

```
\def\insult#1#2{%
  #1 says #2 is a quack.%
  \def\response##1##2{%
    #2 refutes #1's claim, saying, ``#1 is a ##1 ##2''.
    \def\response####1{#1 says,
      ``I'm not a ##1 ##2, but a simple ####1.''
      (#1 leaves.)}%
    Rock on, #2.}}
```

Why must each layer of definitions double the number of `#`s necessary?  The only reason I can think of is to allow 'variadic parameter insertion', but this fails on the first case:

```
\def\use#1#2#3#4#5#6#7#8#9{I want ##1.}
\use{3}cbdefghi
```

obviously does not expand to `I want b`.

So why is this doubling necessary?

Comment: I'm confused: how else would you deal with say `\def\foo#1{\expandafter\def\csname my#1\endcsname##1{#1:##1}` and so on?

Comment: @JosephWright My question only manifests itself one level deeper: Why can't I say `\def\foo#1{\def#1##1{\def##1####1{#1:##1:####1}}}`? What's the reasoning stopping me from using just three `#` instead of four? I'm not saying that different 'scopes' of macro arguments is *bad* – they're certainly a crucial part of how TeX is used – this is a question about why it was implemented as it is.

Comment: Ah, you are specifically wondering about the need for powers of two :-)

Comment: @JosephWright Yes :) I've read the answer before somewhere, but I can't put my finger on it.

Comment: This is surely a duplicate, please search better. However, since at every stage `##` is reduced to `#`, you of course need powers of two.

Comment: @egreg I did try searching :( But that's the point of the duplicate process: to link different wordings of the same question to a canonical answer. Duplicates aren't always *bad*.

Comment: @SeanAllred Is the reason I gave for `#`, `##`, `####`, `########` unclear?

Comment: @egreg It's not unclear, but it does seem arbitrary.

Comment: @SeanAllred Not at all. Your definition of `\use` makes no sense, sorry.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26495/discussion-between-sean-allred-and-egreg).

Comment: it's a duplicate but surely if `##` in a replacement text produces `#` then it is inevitable that you need `####` to put `##` in a nested replacement text?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That's the key information, then. I didn't realize that `##` was itself an 'escape' for `#` macro definition in that sense.

Comment: @SeanAllred that's all it is: there is nothing special about macro parameters with doubled hash, `##1` is nothing more than `##` which produces `#` and `1` which produces 1, it is only when (if) that replacement text is evaluated than the resulting `#1` is seen as a macro parameter reference.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle If a duplicate can't be found (and I'm still looking for one with this information – http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/71633/17423 has the information, but not as the main point), then that sounds like a simple, clear, and sufficient answer.