# substituting "and others" for "et al." in the bst file

Tags: bibtex, chicago-style

I have several references for which I do not have the last authors. In the bibtex file, references have:

> author = {Author1 and Author2 and Author3 and Author4 and Author5 and Author6 and others}

Right now they appear as :

> Author1, Author2, Author3, Author4, Author5, Author6 and others

I want them to appear as:

> Author1, Author2, Author3, Author4, Author5, Author6 et al.

In the bst is say:

```
FUNCTION {format.names}
{ 's :=
  #1 'nameptr :=
  s num.names$ 'numnames :=
  numnames 'namesleft :=
    { namesleft #0 > }
    { "\FormatName{" s nameptr "{ff~}{vv~}{ll}{, jj}" format.name$ * "}" * 't :=
      nameptr #1 >
        { namesleft #1 >
            { ", " * t * }
            { numnames #2 >
                { "," * }
                'skip$
              if$
              t "others" =
                { " et~al." * }
                { " and " * t *  }
              if$
            }
          if$
        }
        't
      if$
      nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
      namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
    }
  while$
}
```

Why doesn't the t "others" = statement work ?

Answer (score 1):

You used the following:
[Make one author's name bold every time it shows up in the bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33330/make-one-authors-name-bold-every-time-it-shows-up-in-the-bibliography)

To put a macro in each name "\FormatName". This needs to be added in the bst:

```
      t "\FormatName{others}" =
```

and it will work.