# BibLaTeX: Rename author name on the fly

Tags: biblatex

I'm using biblatex (backend: biber) and bibliography categories in order to construct automatically a bibliography of all my publications. In principle everything works fine. I just would like to shorten my name in the bibliography since it appears quite oftenly (in order to show also the names of my co-authors I still need to output the names). Here is the relevant name-filter I use:

```
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{catname}%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand*{\mknamesignature}[5]{\def#1{#2|||}}%%%%%%%%%%
\mknamesignature{\highlightname}{Surname}{Prename}{}%%%%%%
    {}%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\DeclareIndexNameFormat{catname}%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    {%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \mknamesignature{\currentsignature}{#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}%%%
    \ifdefequal{\highlightname}{\currentsignature}%%%%%%%%
        {\addtocategory{catname}{\thefield{entrykey}}}%%%%
        {}%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
}%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\AtDataInput{\indexnames[catname][1-99]{author}}%%%%%%%%%%
```

I then output the category just by:

```
\printbibliography[category=catname]
```

Is there a way to change the name of the entries added on the fly (of course not in the bibtex-file)? So, if my bibliography shows "Surname, Prename ..." I'd like something like "SP ...".

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can adjust this solution http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/211821/16895

Answer (score 1):

According to Guido's suggestion I use the following modified code now (of course it also "initializes" all other prename- and surname entries, but for my purpose it works):

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%Replace my name in the bib by initials on the fly...%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{xstring}%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\noexpandarg\exploregroups%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\makeatletter%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\let\orig@blx@bbl@entry\blx@bbl@entry%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\def\blx@bbl@entry#1\endentry{%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\StrSubstitute{#1}{Prename}{P\bibinitperiod}[\Result]%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\expandafter\StrSubstitute\expandafter{\Result}{Surname}{S\bibinitperiod%
}[\Result]%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\expandafter\orig@blx@bbl@entry\Result\endentry}%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\makeatother%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

Thanks again and all the best, Christian