# Author highlighting with biblatex-apa

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

I'm trying to implement the author highlighting provided here:

[Make one author's name bold every time it shows up in the bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/211821/48182)

The solution works fine until i activate the apa style for biblatex.
Heres my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[
  babel,
  german=quotes
]{csquotes}

\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  %style=apa, %<===========uncomment me!!
  sortcites=true,
  sorting=nyt,
  hyperref=true,
  backref=true,
  alldates=iso8601
]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{zongker_chicken_2006,
    title = {Chicken chicken chicken: Chicken chicken},
    volume = {12},
    url = {http://www.superfrink.net/athenaeum/dougz.pdf},
    shorttitle = {Chicken chicken chicken},
    pages = {16--21},
    number = {5},
    journaltitle = {Annals of Improbable Research},
    author = {Zongker, Doug},
    urldate = {2013-04-05},
    date = {2006}
}

@article{zongker_chicken_2007,
    title = {Chicken chicken chicken: Chicken chicken},
    volume = {12},
    url = {http://www.superfrink.net/athenaeum/dougz.pdf},
    shorttitle = {Chicken chicken chicken},
    pages = {16--21},
    number = {5},
    journaltitle = {Annals of Improbable Research},
    author = {OhterZongker, Doug},
    urldate = {2013-04-05},
    date = {2007}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{ngerman}{ngerman-apa}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/211821/48182
\newcommand{\makeauthorbold}[1]{%
\DeclareNameFormat{author}{%
  \edef\tempname{{#1}}%
  \ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{1}
    {\ifnumequal{\value{liststop}}{1}
      {\expandafter\ifstrequal\tempname{##1}{\textbf{##1\addcomma\addspace ##4\addcomma\isdot}}{##1\addcomma\addspace ##4\addcomma\isdot}}
      {\expandafter\ifstrequal\tempname{##1}{\textbf{##1\addcomma\addspace ##4}}{##1\addcomma\addspace ##4}}}
    {\ifnumless{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststop}}
      {\expandafter\ifstrequal\tempname{##1}{\textbf{\addcomma\addspace ##1\addcomma\addspace ##4}}{\addcomma\addspace ##1\addcomma\addspace ##4}}
      {\expandafter\ifstrequal\tempname{##1}{\textbf{\addcomma\addspace ##1\addcomma\addspace ##4\addcomma\isdot}}{\addcomma\addspace ##1\addcomma\addspace ##4\addcomma\isdot}}%
    }%
}%
}
\makeauthorbold{Zongker}

\begin{document}
\fullcite{zongker_chicken_2006}


\fullcite{zongker_chicken_2007}
\end{document}
```

Heres the different output without style=apa

[image: bold]

with style=apa

[image: not bold]

Why doesn't my command overwrite the apa style ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*This post is now updated to work with `biblatex` >= 3.3 and `biblatex-apa` >= 6.8. The only change necessary is that the macro that was called `name:apa:last-first` in versions < 3.3 is now called `name:apa:family-given`. The patching has to be adapted to that name change. The old version can be found in the history of this answer.*

The code you used does not work because `biblatex-apa` does not use the `author` format, but uses its own `apaauthor`.

I suggest you take [Audrey](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4483/audrey)'s approach to [Make specific author bold using biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/73136/35864) with hashes as explained in [Highlight an author in bibliography using biblatex allowing bibliography style to format it](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/274436/35864)

The only thing we need to consider here is that the macro you need to patch is now called `name:apa:family-given`.

MWE (of course the hash `086a2ad072f9903168e35b73cd394263` is specific to the MWE, read about how to find out the hash in the answer linked to above)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage[
  babel,
  german=quotes
]{csquotes}

\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=apa,
  sorting=nyt,
  backref=true,
  alldates=iso
]{biblatex}

\newcommand*{\boldnames}{}

\newcommand*{\doboldhashes}[1]{%
  \iffieldequalstr{hash}{#1}
    {\bfseries\listbreak}
    {}}%

\newbibmacro*{name:bold}{%
  \forlistloop{\doboldhashes}{\boldnames}%
}

\xpretobibmacro{name:apa:family-given}{\begingroup\usebibmacro{name:bold}}{}{}
\xpretobibmacro{name:delim}{\begingroup\normalfont}{}{}

\xapptobibmacro{name:apa:family-given}{\endgroup}{}{}
\xapptobibmacro{name:delim}{\endgroup}{}{}

\renewcommand*{\boldnames}{}
\forcsvlist{\listadd\boldnames}
  {{086a2ad072f9903168e35b73cd394263}}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{zongker_chicken_2006,
    title = {Chicken chicken chicken: Chicken chicken},
    volume = {12},
    url = {http://www.superfrink.net/athenaeum/dougz.pdf},
    shorttitle = {Chicken chicken chicken},
    pages = {16--21},
    number = {5},
    journaltitle = {Annals of Improbable Research},
    author = {Zongker, Doug},
    urldate = {2013-04-05},
    date = {2006}
}

@article{zongker_chicken_2007,
    title = {Chicken chicken chicken: Chicken chicken},
    volume = {12},
    url = {http://www.superfrink.net/athenaeum/dougz.pdf},
    shorttitle = {Chicken chicken chicken},
    pages = {16--21},
    number = {5},
    journaltitle = {Annals of Improbable Research},
    author = {OhterZongker, Doug},
    urldate = {2013-04-05},
    date = {2007}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\fullcite{zongker_chicken_2006}

\fullcite{zongker_chicken_2007}
\end{document}
```

[image]