# Make one author's name bold every time it shows up in the bibliography (when there are two author's with the same last name but different first name)

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, moderncv

This answer ([Make one author's name bold every time it shows up in the bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33330/make-one-authors-name-bold-every-time-it-shows-up-in-the-bibliography?newreg=887f690669a74aea8dd734ac90f80f3d)) works fine, but when there are two authors with the same last name and different first names it makes both of them bold. How can I make only one of them bold?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\usepackage[sorting=ydnt,dashed=false,backend=bibtex,maxcitenames=4, mincitenames=4,maxbibnames=500, minbibnames=500]{biblatex} 
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1in, left=1in, right=1in]{geometry}
% suppress the "In:" for @article (only): 
\renewbibmacro{in:} 
{% `    
\ifentrytype{article}{} 
{% 
    \printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}} 

\newcommand{\makeauthorbold}[1]{%
    \DeclareNameFormat{author}{%
    \edef\tempname{{#1}}%
    \ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{1}
    {\ifnumequal{\value{liststop}}{1}
        {\expandafter\ifstrequal\tempname{##1}{\textbf{##1\addcomma\addspace ##4\addcomma\isdot}}{##1\addcomma\addspace ##4\addcomma\isdot}}
        {\expandafter\ifstrequal\tempname{##1}{\textbf{##1\addcomma\addspace ##4}}{##1\addcomma\addspace ##4}}}
    {\ifnumless{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststop}}
        {\expandafter\ifstrequal\tempname{##1}{\textbf{\addcomma\addspace ##1\addcomma\addspace ##4}}{\addcomma\addspace ##1\addcomma\addspace ##4}}
        {\expandafter\ifstrequal\tempname{##1}{\textbf{\addcomma\addspace ##1\addcomma\addspace ##4\addcomma\isdot}}{\addcomma\addspace ##1\addcomma\addspace ##4\addcomma\isdot}}%
    }%
}%
}
\makeauthorbold{Doe}
\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
{\list
{\printtext[labelnumberwidth]{% label format from numeric.bbx
        \printfield{prefixnumber}%
        \printfield{labelnumber}}}
{\setlength{\topsep}{0pt}% layout parameters from moderncvstyleclassic.sty
    \setlength{\labelwidth}{\hintscolumnwidth}%
    \setlength{\labelsep}{\separatorcolumnwidth}%
    \leftmargin\labelwidth%
    \advance\leftmargin\labelsep}%
\sloppy\clubpenalty4000\widowpenalty4000}
{\endlist}
{\item}

\moderncvstyle{banking} 
\moderncvcolor{black}  

\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}
\addbibresource{pub.bib}
\title{Curriculum Vitae}                            
\address{Here}{There}
\phone[fixed]{+66~66~(666)~6666}
\phone[fax]{+66~66~(666)~6666}
\email{john.doe@johndoe.edu}                  
\homepage{johndoe.com}  


\makeatother
\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\nocite{*}
\setlength\hintscolumnwidth{20pt} 
\setlength\separatorcolumnwidth{20pt} 
\printbibliography[title={Publications}]
\end{document}
```

and the pub.bib files looks like:

```
@Article{pmid01,
Author="Doe, J. and Sam, A. and Kim, B",
Title="{Making author bold}",
Journal="Latex",
Year="2015",
Pages=" ",
Month="Jul"
}
@Article{pmid02,
Author="Doe, J. and Sam, A. and Doe, F",
Title="{Making one author bold}",
Journal="Latex",
Year="2014",
Pages=" ",
Month="Jul"
}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem. The answer you linked certainly appears to test the author's full name, while you only reference the surname in your fragment.

Comment: I edited the code to make it compilable. However I tried it with full name and it didn't work. When I use the full name it doesn't make any of them bold, and when I only use last name it makes both of them bold. Thanks