# custom bst file? "Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations"

Tags: bibtex, natbib

I was trying to follow https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/33379/21586 but it seems like i have a problem with the bst file (before i even make any changes in the answer).

I did the following:

1. `kpsewhich plain.bst`
2. `cp <path from above> <path where my .tex and .bib files are>/myplainbib.bst`
3. change `\bibliographystyle{plain}` to `\bibliographystyle{myplainbib}`
4. build (i'm using LaTeXTools with Sublime Text 3)

i get the following:

```
Package natbib Error: Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations. [...mand\NAT@force@numbers{}\NAT@force@numbers]
```

What's going on? That's *without* changing the bst at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take it you're using the `natbib` citation management package with the option `authoryear`.

The `plain` bibliography style is set up to only produce numeric-style citation callouts. Making a copy of `plain.bst` and naming it `myplainbib.bst` -- unsurprisingly... -- does not change the (lack of) capabilities of the `plain` style with regard to the way citation call-outs can be formatted.

If you're OK with the formatting that `plain` applies to the typeset bibliographic entries but wish to produce authoryear-style citation call-outs, you should use the `plainnat` bibliography style, which is part of the `natbib` citation management package, for the basis of the modifications described in  https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/33379/5001.

Comment: not knowing what i'm doing at all, i followed your suggestion (i think) and did `kpsewhich plainnat.bst` and copied and modified and referred to that style instead. That seemed to work.

Comment: @Michael - Good to know my suggestion worked for you. :-)