# All authors and year bold with modified IEEEtran .bst file

Tags: bibtex

I am new to this topic. I am working with LyX and BibTeX. I want to include a Bibliography, using the `IEEEtran.bst` style. So far so good.
But I simply want to have every author's name bold (ideally not the 'and' at the end of the authors' name list) plus the year of publishing. I was trying to change the function ([Shown in this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/361666/why-is-the-bst-hack-for-highlighting-author-name-not-working), making one specific author name bold) to work that way, so a 'highlight.author.year' function, but I do not get it.
Can someone please help me out here? It should not be that difficult, as I only have to change the function from the other post, but I'm struggling to find a working solution.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a solution for the authors' names:

```
FUNCTION {highlight.bolden}
{ duplicate$ empty$
     { pop$ "" }
     { "\textbf{" swap$ * "}" * }
   if$
}
```

and call the function in

```
FUNCTION {format.names}
{ 'bibinfo :=
  duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$ {
  this.to.prev.status
  this.status.std
  's :=
  "" 't :=
  #1 'nameptr :=
  s num.names$ 'numnames :=
  numnames 'namesleft :=
    { namesleft #0 > }
    { s nameptr
      name.format.string
      format.name$
      highlight.bolden
      bibinfo bibinfo.check
      't :=
.
.
.
```

Now the only problem, what is left, is finding the right spot to call the hiighlight.bolden function for the year. I tried to place it into the...

```
FUNCTION {format.date}
```

...and into the...

```
FUNCTION {format.date.electronic}
```

..but both did not work... Has someone an idea where to place it, to bold the year??

Many thanks!