# Change "et al" in bibliography in case that contain one specific author in there

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, highlighting

I am trying to change the et~al. that appears in the bibliography in the case that inside the extra (et~al) authors there is an author that I am trying to make bold in the bibliography using the answer of @LawrenceCrosby [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/328286/120578)

My code is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{MyBibliography.bib}
  @article{cite1,
    author={Konstantinos Leledakis},
    title={An Article},
    year={2019},
    journal={Some Journal}
  }
  @article{cite2,
    author={Another Author and Konstantinos Leledakis},
    title={A Book},
    year={2017},
    journal={A publisher}
  }
  @book{cite3,
    author={Another SomeAuthor and One AnotherAuthor and SomeOther UnKnownAuthor and Konstantinos Leledakis},
    title={A Book},
    year={1988},
    publisher={Someone}
    }
  @book{cite4,
    author={Another Author and An UnknownAuthor and SomeOther UnKnownAuthor},
    title={A Book},
    year={2015},
    publisher={A publisher}
  }
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,maxnames=2, minnames=2]{biblatex}
\usepackage{etoolbox}


\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{andothers={\ifthenelse{\boolean{bold}}{et~al(including Leledakis, K.)}{et~al}\adddot}}


\newboolean{bold}
\newcommand{\makeauthorbold}[1]{%
  \setboolean{bold}{false}
  \DeclareNameFormat{author}{%
    \ifthenelse{\value{listcount}=1}
    {%
      {\expandafter\ifstrequal\expandafter{\namepartfamily}{#1}{\setboolean{bold}{true}\mkbibbold{\namepartfamily\addcomma\addspace \namepartgiveni}}{\namepartfamily\addcomma\addspace \namepartgiveni}}
      %
    }{\ifnumless{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststop}}
        {\expandafter\ifstrequal\expandafter{\namepartfamily}{#1}{\setboolean{bold}{true}\mkbibbold{\addcomma\addspace \namepartfamily\addcomma\addspace \namepartgiveni}}{\addcomma\addspace \namepartfamily\addcomma\addspace \namepartgiveni}}
        {\expandafter\ifstrequal\expandafter{\namepartfamily}{#1}{\setboolean{bold}{true}\mkbibbold{\addcomma\addspace \namepartfamily\addcomma\addspace \namepartgiveni\addcomma\isdot}}{\addcomma\addspace \namepartfamily\addcomma\addspace \namepartgiveni\addcomma\isdot}}%
      }
    \ifthenelse{\value{listcount}<\value{liststop}}
    {\addcomma\space}
  }
}

%\makeauthorbold{Leledakis}


\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{andothers={et~al}} % To translate "et al."

\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{firstinits=true, uniquename=init}

\addbibresource{MyBibliography.bib}
\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\addspace} % Should add the comma, but somehow doesn't work

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

This has two problems:

1. If I comment in (I mean enable) the commented out command `%\makeauthorbold{Leledakis}` and enable it. Te result from:

[image]

(that contains some et~al).becomes:

[image]

Where the name is already highlighted but the et~al. part is missing at all.

PS: I tested the code without my changes too, but it still misses the et. al. part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\DeclareNameFormat{author}` is a modification of the original name format that leaves a few things to be desired.

1. It can't deal with "von" parts and "Jr." parts.
2. It can't deal with "et al.", because it is missing a call to the standard `\usebibmacro{name:andothers}`.
3. On a modern `biblatex` version it will even produce an error due to a syntax error. (The last `\ifthenelse` is missing a *false* branch. See also https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/874.)

I suggest you use one of the more robust versions to make your name bold suggested in [Make specific author bold using biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/73136/35864). As far as I can see none of the solution bolds the "et al." if it "contains" the relevant name out of the box, but we can add that.

As basis I'm using [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/416416/35864) that uses hashes, but allows for a convenient interface to retrieve them. The tricky bit is to check whether or not the "et al." also contains a name to be highlighted. We do this by looping over all remaining names in an `\indexnames` that otherwise prints nothing.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,
            maxnames=2, minnames=2,
            giveninits=true, uniquename=init]{biblatex}

\makeatletter
% setup for auxiliary bib file
\def\hlblx@bibfile@name{\jobname -boldnames.bib}
\newwrite\hlblx@bibfile
\immediate\openout\hlblx@bibfile=\hlblx@bibfile@name

\newcounter{hlblx@name}
\setcounter{hlblx@name}{0}

% write names to auxiliary bib file and push hash to bold list
\newcommand*{\hlblx@writenametobib}[1]{%
  \stepcounter{hlblx@name}%
  \edef\hlblx@tmp@nocite{%
    \noexpand\AfterPreamble{%
      \noexpand\setbox0\noexpand\vbox{%
        \noexpand\hlblx@getmethehash{hlblx@name@\the\value{hlblx@name}}}}%
  }%
  \hlblx@tmp@nocite
  \immediate\write\hlblx@bibfile{%
    @misc{hlblx@name@\the\value{hlblx@name}, author = {\unexpanded{#1}}, %
          options = {dataonly=true},}%
  }%
}

\AtEndDocument{%
  \closeout\hlblx@bibfile}

\addbibresource{\hlblx@bibfile@name}

% extract hashes from bib file
\newcommand*{\hlbxl@boldhashes}{}
\DeclareNameFormat{hlblx@hashextract}{%
  \xifinlist{\thefield{hash}}{\hlbxl@boldhashes}
    {}
    {\listxadd{\hlbxl@boldhashes}{\thefield{fullhash}}}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\hlblx@getmethehash}
  {}
  {\printnames[hlblx@hashextract][1-999]{author}}
  {}
  {}

% add and reset list of bold names
\newcommand*{\addboldnames}{\forcsvlist\hlblx@writenametobib}
\newcommand*{\resetboldnames}{\def\hlbxl@boldhashes{}}

\newcommand*{\mkboldifhashinlist}[1]{%
  \xifinlist{\thefield{hash}}{\hlbxl@boldhashes}
    {\mkbibbold{#1}}
    {#1}}

\newtoggle{boldnameincluded}
\newbibmacro*{name:flagbold}{%
  \def\do##1{\iffieldequalstr{hash}{##1}{\global\toggletrue{boldnameincluded}\listbreak}{}}%
  \dolistloop{\hlbxl@boldhashes}%
}

\DeclareNameWrapperFormat{boldifhashinlist}{%
  \renewcommand*{\mkbibcompletename}{\mkboldifhashinlist}%
  #1}

\DeclareNameWrapperAlias{sortname}{default}
\DeclareNameWrapperAlias{default}{boldifhashinlist}

\DeclareIndexNameFormat{flagbold}{%
  \usebibmacro{name:flagbold}}

\newcounter{boldflagcount}
\newcommand*{\mkbibboldandothers}[2]{%
  \iftoggle{boldnameincluded}
    {\mkbibbold{#2#1}}
    {#2}}

\renewbibmacro*{name:andothers}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststop}}}
    and
    test \ifmorenames
  }
    {\ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{1}
       {\finalandcomma}
       {}%
     \global\togglefalse{boldnameincluded}%
     \ifnumgreater{\value{listtotal}}{\value{listcount}}
       {\defcounter{boldflagcount}{\value{listcount}+1}%
        \expandafter\def\expandafter\hlblx@currname\expandafter{\currentname}%
        \indexnames[flagbold][\the\value{boldflagcount}-\the\value{listtotal}]{\hlblx@currname}}%
       {}%
     \printdelim{andothersdelim}%
     \bibstring[\mkbibboldandothers{ (incuding K.~Leledakis)}]{andothers}}
    {}}
\makeatother


\addboldnames{Konstantinos Leledakis}


\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{cite1,
  author  = {Konstantinos Leledakis},
  title   = {An Article},
  year    = {2019},
  journal = {Some Journal},
}
@article{cite2,
  author  = {Another Author and Konstantinos Leledakis},
  title   = {A Book},
  year    = {2017},
  journal = {A publisher},
}
@book{cite3,
  author    = {Another SomeAuthor and One AnotherAuthor
               and SomeOther UnKnownAuthor and Konstantinos Leledakis},
  title     = {A Book},
  year      = {1988},
  publisher = {Someone},
}
@book{cite4,
  author    = {Another Author and An UnknownAuthor
               and SomeOther UnKnownAuthor},
  title     = {A Book},
  year      = {2015},
  publisher = {A publisher},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Author, A. and **K. Leledakis** (2017). “A Book”. In: A publisher.//Author, A., A. UnknownAuthor, et al. (2015). A Book. A publisher.//**Leledakis, K.** (2019). “An Article”. In: Some Journal.//SomeAuthor, A., O. AnotherAuthor, **et al. (incuding K. Leledakis)** (1988). A Book. Someone.]

If you are looking to format a list of publications for your CV, you may want to have a look at [`biblatex-publist`](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-publist).

*edited* to use a more elegant version to format complete names. `\DeclareNameWrapperFormat` and `\mkbibcompletename` are only available in `biblatex` v3.12 (2018-10-30) and v3.13 (2019-08-17), respectively. Please refer to the edit history if you are using an older version of `biblatex`.

Comment: Thank you very much @moewe... I had already fixed the issue of the linked answer (That could not print "et al") and felt that I could do it to use the addition I was looking for (exactly your output! -that for a moment thought is not clear in my question-) but possibly I was still away from that. I am going to post an answer in that question when finish in order at least to print the missing for now "at al." part. Thank you for the suggested package too. I will have a look.