# How to print one bibliography including cited and non-cited references?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, texmaker, multibib

I'm writing a CV-like document in order to be able to officially mentor PhD students. I face a major issue regarding the bibliography.

My bibliography must be managed like this:

1. multi-sections: one for journals, one for books, one for conference proceedings...
2. chronological or reversed chronological order
3. my name must be highlighted
4. references: cited **AND** non-cited ones

I'm able to solve points 1 to 3 BUT each time I want to print cited references with non-cited ones, cited references are placed at the beginning of each  sub-sections (journals, books...) without keeping the original citing order (chronological or reversed chronological). How to solve this issue?

My template use the `multibib` package and `BibTeX`.

Hereafter, an example of my code:

```
 \documentclass[french]{hdrapplication}

    \usepackage{ae,lmodern}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{textcomp}

    \usepackage{textgreek}
    \usepackage{hyperref}

    \usepackage{array}
    \usepackage{color}

    \usepackage{xstring}

    %\usepackage[resetlabels]{multibib} % Present in the appropriate cls file
    \newcites{bookall}{Books}
    \newcites{journalall}{Journals}
    \newcites{proceedingsall}{Conferences}
    \newcites{othersall}{Others}

    \begin{document}

    My first publication \citeproceedings{RN1} was published in 2006...
    With this Phd student, we publised 2 papers \citejournal{RN2}\citeproceedings{RN3}...

    \section{References}

        % Name & bold
        \def\FormatName#1{%
            \IfSubStr{#1}{StefM}{\textbf{#1}}{#1}%
        }

        \begingroup
            \makeatletter
                \renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{}
                \renewcommand{\refname}{}%
            \makeatother   

            \bibliographystylebook{unsrt}
            \bibliographybook{myBiblio_book}
            \nocitebook{*}

            \bibliographystylejournal{unsrt}
            \bibliographyjournal{myBiblio_journal}
            \nocitejournal{*}

            \bibliographystyleproceedings{unsrt}
            \bibliographyproceedings{myBiblio_proceedings}
            \nociteproceedings{*}

            \bibliographystyleotherss{unsrt}
           \bibliographyothers{myBiblio_others}
           \nociteothers{*}
        \endgroup
\end{document}
```

---

Configuration: - TeXMaker 5.0.3 - MiKTeX 2.9 - BiBTeX

Comment: IUse the `\nocite{*}` in the preamble. This being said, it is quite easy to obtain what you want with `biblatex`: e.g.  `\printbibliography[type=book, heading=subbibliography, title=Books]`.

Comment: Thanks @Bernard for your quick answer. According to me, `\nocite{*}` can't be in the preamble. I tried to use `biblatex` also without success... Indeed, I can't have cited AND non-cited references at the same time! Maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: Maybe this is a problem with you (non-standard) document class? I don't know where to find it, so I can't test.

Comment: I use the hdrapplication document class from Stephane Galland that you can download [there](https://github.com/gallandarakhneorg/tex-templates/tree/master/hdr/hdrapplication).

Comment: `\nocite{*}` should *not* appear in the preamble.  From the BibTeX documentation: "Giving this command, in essence, `\nocite`s all the entries in the database, in database order, at the very spot in your document where you give the command."  So the best place to input `\nocite{*}` is probably just before `\printbibliography`.

Comment: It works now combining your 2 propositions! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Please find hereafter, the solution that works for me!

```
\documentclass[french]{hdrapplication}

\usepackage{ae,lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{color}

\usepackage{xstring}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric-comp,sorting=ynt,defernumbers=true,maxbibnames=99,url=false]{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\addbibresource{myBiblio.bib}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33330/make-one-authors-name-bold-every-time-it-shows-up-in-the-bibliography
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newboolean{bold}
\newcommand{\makeauthorsbold}[1]{%
  \DeclareNameFormat{author}{%
  \setboolean{bold}{false}%
    \renewcommand{\do}[1]{\expandafter\ifstrequal\expandafter{\namepartfamily}{####1}{\setboolean{bold}{true}}{}}%
    \docsvlist{#1}%
    \ifthenelse{\value{listcount}=1}
    {%
      {\expandafter\ifthenelse{\boolean{bold}}{\mkbibbold{\namepartfamily\addcomma\addspace \namepartgiveni}}{\namepartfamily\addcomma\addspace \namepartgiveni}}%
    }{\ifnumless{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststop}}
      {\expandafter\ifthenelse{\boolean{bold}}{\mkbibbold{\addcomma\addspace \namepartfamily\addcomma\addspace \namepartgiveni}}{\addcomma\addspace \namepartfamily\addcomma\addspace \namepartgiveni}}%
      {\expandafter\ifthenelse{\boolean{bold}}{\mkbibbold{\addcomma\addspace \namepartfamily\addcomma\addspace \namepartgiveni\addcomma\isdot}}{\addcomma\addspace \namepartfamily\addcomma\addspace \namepartgiveni\addcomma\isdot}}%
      }
    \ifthenelse{\value{listcount}<\value{liststop}}
    {\addcomma\space}{}
  }
}

\makeauthorsbold{StefM}

\begin{document}
     My report...

    \nocite{*}
    \printbibliography[type=inbook, heading=subbibliography, title=Books]
    \printbibliography[type=article, heading=subbibliography, title=Journal,resetnumbers=false]
    \printbibliography[type=inproceedings, heading=subbibliography, title=Conference proceedings,resetnumbers=false]
    \printbibliography[type=misc, heading=subbibliography, title=Others,resetnumbers=false]
\end{document}
```