# Abbreviate resolved abbreviations in authors' first names in biblatex

Tags: biblatex

I like to resolve abbreviated first names in my `.bib` file. For example, if the author of a book is given as `Paul G. J. Smith`, I will resolve the abbreviations as `Paul G[eorge] J[ohn] Smith` in my `.bib` file.

Some journals, however, specifically want the names of the authors to be printed as they appear in the cited work. The entry for Smith, therefore, should appear as `Smith, Paul G. J.` in the printed bibliography.

What do I need to do in `biblatex` in order to tell it to replace a sequence beginning with `[` and ending with `]` with a dot `.`? Please suggest a command I can put in the preamble of my `.tex` file. I have a long list of `biblatex` tweaks in my preambles, and I would prefer to keep them all there, if possible.

A MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[
        bibstyle = authoryear,
        citestyle = authoryear-comp,
        sorting = nyt,
        language = american,
        abbreviate = false,
        backend = biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{smith2006,
    AUTHOR = "Paul G[eorge] J[ohn] Smith",
    TITLE = "My life with the Beatles",
    YEAR = "2006"}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\noindent
Text \parencite{smith2006}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: ``Biblatex`` knows a ``firstinits=true`` option that unfortunately abbreviates all first names. It looks like you are searching for some "conditional" ``firstinits`` setting, that abbreviates all but the first first name. I didn't have a look at the ``biblatex`` style source code yet but maybe it is possible to build a macro that only abbreviates the n>1 first names.

Comment: @BenediktBauer But that is _not_ what I am trying to accomplish. If the author's name is given as `Paul George Smith`, then I don't want to abbreviate anything. What I need is a command that searches the `author` entry for sequences beginning with `[` and ending with `]`, and replaces that sequence with `.`. I believe this should be quite easy once you know your way around things like that. I'm just not such a person.

Comment: OK, then I just misunderstood your intentions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The built-in way to do such things is with the biblatex `\DeclareSourcemap` macro. To use this, you have to be using `biber`. This method is preferable as it has semantic access to biblatex native objects. Try adding this to the preamble of your example above:

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=author, 
            match=\regexp{\[[^]]+\]},
            replace=.]
    }
  }
}
```

There are many other things you can do with this, see section 4.5.2 of the current biblatex manual. This is completely style independent, it alters the data stream from the .bib before biblatex even sees it.

Comment: Works like a charm!

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure if this is the right way, but it seems to work (part of the code is from [this answer by Marco Daniel](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34133/4427)), particularly in the usage of `\DeclareNameFormat` and `\DeclareNameAlias`. Maybe experts in `biblatex` can improve it.

The following method uses `l3regex` to get rid of the bracketed parts:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[
        bibstyle = authoryear,
        citestyle = authoryear-comp,
        sorting = nyt,
        language = american,
        abbreviate = false,
        backend = biber]{biblatex}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first} % for styles where names are sorted last-first
\DeclareNameFormat{last-first}{%
  \usebibmacro{name:last-first}{#1}{\removebrackets{#3}}{#5}{#7}%
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{first-last} % for styles where names are sorted first-last
\DeclareNameFormat{first-last}{%
  \usebibmacro{name:first-last}{#1}{\removebrackets{#3}}{#5}{#7}%
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}

\usepackage{xparse,l3regex}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\removebrackets}{m}
 {
  \sverre_remove_brackets:n { #1 }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \sverre_remove_brackets:n #1
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l__sverre_input_tl { #1 }
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { \[.*?\] } { \. } \l__sverre_input_tl
  \tl_use:N \l__sverre_input_tl
 }
\tl_new:N \l__sverre_input_tl
\ExplSyntaxOff


\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{smith2006,
    AUTHOR = "Paul G[eorge] J[ohn] Smith",
    TITLE = "My life with the Beatles",
    YEAR = "2006"}
@BOOK{smith2006x,
    AUTHOR = "Paul G[eorge] J[ohn] Smith and Knuth, Donald E[rving]",
    TITLE = "My life with the Beatles",
    YEAR = "2006"}
@BOOK{smith2006y,
    AUTHOR = "Paul G[eorge] J[ohn] Smith and X, Y and A, B and C, D and E, F and G, H",
    TITLE = "My life with the Beatles",
    YEAR = "2006"}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\noindent
Text \parencite{smith2006}.

\parencite{smith2006x}
\parencite{smith2006y}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This solution, seems, however, to be tied to the specific style used. If you use the default style `numeric` instead of `authoryear`, then this solution doesn't change anything. It would be nice to have a solution that wasn't tied to a specific style like this.

Comment: @Sverre I guess it depends on the bib macros used with the chosen style.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. But I think you'll see too that if you just comment out the first three options of the `\usepackage[]{biblatex}` command (such that it resorts to the default `numeric`), it will print `Smith, Paul G[eorge] J[ohn]`.

Comment: @Sverre It depends on what method is used for typesetting the bibliography, which in turn depends on the options. I just don't know what to change here.

Comment: Given that the `numeric` style orders the names first-last, I just changed your `last-first` to `first-last`, and that did the trick. I'm updating your answer to show this.

Comment: Dunno why the links and pictures got messed up when I edited your answer. Sorry bout that.