# Typeset just the first letter in a group

Tags: text-manipulation

How can I typeset (print) just the first letter of a group of text?

For instance, how does `biblatex` or `bibtex` determine the first initials of a name?

MWE to get started:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\begin{document}

This prints \firstinit{just the first letter}.

My hero is \firstinit{John} \firstinit{Paul} Jones.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The routine `\justfirst` needs its argument *not* in braces, but terminated by a known quantity.  Thus, `\firstinit` conspires with `\justfirst`, unbeknownst to the user, to provide it just so, with a `\relax` as the terminator, because it is unlikely to show up in user text.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\def\firstinit#1{\justfirst#1\relax}
\def\justfirst#1#2\relax{#1}

\begin{document}

This prints \firstinit{just the first letter}.

My hero is \firstinit{John} \firstinit{Paul} Jones.

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Of course, if you meant for multi-worded phrases to output the first letter of **each** word, that is slightly more difficult.  REVISED to take advantage of recursion; RE-REVISED to eliminate use of packages. RE-RE-REVISED to prevent defeat by a "llama".

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\def\firstinit#1{\justfirst#1 \relax\relax}
\def\justfirst#1#2 #3\relax{#1\if\relax#3\else{} \justfirst#3\relax\fi}
\begin{document}
This prints \firstinit{just the first llama in the list}.

My hero is \firstinit{John} \firstinit{Paul} Jones.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice. I was mostly interested in the first case; The edit on the second version is much nicer in the code, and also seems like the spacing is better in typesetting.

Comment: Being defeated by a llama deserves a second upvote!

Comment: @ChrisH  Well, it was either that, or else implement a `[Chilean]` package option.