# Defining abbreviation command

Tags: macros

I want to make a command that I say for example:

```
\newcommand{abbre}{...}

\def\abbre{Modular Response}
```

And `\abbre` should display `MR.`

Thanks

Comment: It is not clear to me what you really want.  After `\newcommand` must be a macro, eg `\newcommand\abbre{...}`. In your case it makes no difference in using `\def` or not.

Comment: That's true, I don't need the \def command. But what I really want to know is how do I define the command \abbre for obtaining the initials of a phrase.

Comment: Look at the [glossaries](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Glossary) package, especially the ``\newacronym{MR}{mr}{Module Response}`` command and then use ``\gls{MR}`` in your text.

Comment: There are dedicated packages for abbreviations. Besides the already mentioned [`glossaries`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/glossaries) there's also [`acronym`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/acronym) and [`acro`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/acro). I suggest you take a look at them.

Comment: Please add the content of your comment in your question, as the question itself is not clear enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modified from my answer at [Typeset just the first letter in a group](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/166590/typeset-just-the-first-letter-in-a-group/166592#166592) to: 1) remove the space between letters; 2) present only the letters of the capitalized words of the phrase, and to 3) create a macro of the abbreviated name to recall the original phrase (see the example of `\MRT` in my MWE.).

This allows you to work in both directions.  For example, I can speak of `Modular Response of Tissue"` and abbreviate it as `\abbre{Modular Response of Tissue}` to give `MRT`.  On the other hand, having done the abbreviation once, I can formulate my document with `MRT` for the acronym and `\MRT` to get the phrase `Modular Response of Tissue`.

The most recently defined acronym may be re-accessed with `\theabbre`.  If you don't want the acronym to print out with the invocation of `\abbre{}`, pass it the optional argument `[q]` for "quiet" as in `\abbre[q]{Modular Response of Tissue}`.  You can later access it the acronym with `\theabbre`, if it is the most recently defined acronym.

Abbreviations are not limited in their length.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\newcommand\abbre[2][v]{\def\theabbre{}%
  \expandafter\justfirstCAPS#2 \relax\relax\if q#1\else\theabbre\fi%
  \expandafter\def\csname\theabbre\endcsname{#2}}
\makeatletter
\def\justfirstCAPS#1#2 #3\relax{\ifnum`#1>`@\ifnum`#1<`[%
  \protected@edef\theabbre{\theabbre#1}\fi\fi%
  \if\relax#3\else\justfirstCAPS#3\relax\fi}
\makeatother
\textwidth 5.5in
\def\x{Laughing My A\$\$ Off Rolling On The Floor, Biting The Carpet, Scaring 
The Cat, Nearly Dying By Falling Out Of The Window In Front Of A Guy Who 
Looks Like Bill Gates, Who Then Horrified, Runs Out On The Street And Is 
Accidentally Killed By A Yellow Bulldozer}
\parskip 1em
\begin{document}
This prints \abbre{Modular Response of Tissue} as the abbreviation to Modular 
  Response of Tissue, which can thereafter be recalled with the
shorthand \verb|\MRT| as \MRT.  The most recently defined acronym is \theabbre.

Abbreviations are not limited to two, three, or even nine characters:

One of the longest internet acronyms, according to 
\texttt{www.urbandictionary.com}, is\\
\abbre{\x},\\ which stands for ``\x''.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Arturo You are welcome.  One of the ways you might want to use it (not mentioned in the answer is `\abbre[q]{Computer Aided Tomography}\CAT{} (\theabbre)`.  If you would prefer that `\abbre` just prints out the actual words (not the acronym), saving the acronym in `\theabbre`, I could make that change.

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\firstL[1]{\@car #1\@empty\@nil}
\newcommand*\firstLetter[1]{\expandafter\@firstLetter#1 \@nil}
\def\@firstLetter#1 #2\@nil{%
  \firstL{#1}\ifx\\#2\\\else\@ReturnAfterFi{\@firstLetter#2\@nil}\fi}
\long\def\@ReturnAfterFi#1\fi{\fi#1}
\makeatother
\newcommand\abbre{Modular Response}
\begin{document}

\abbre~is the long version and \firstLetter{\abbre} the
short one. And \firstLetter{Modular Response} also. And
\firstLetter{This Is Also Returned With The first Letter}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. And what could I do if I want the \shortAbbr command to give me the capital leters in a phrase? For example with the phrase Modular Response of Tissues it should give MRT.

Comment: see my edited answer.

Answer (score 2):

I can offer a more short macro (only two lines of the \abbre macro):

```
\def\abbre#1{\expandafter\abbreA#1 \relax/ }
\def\abbreA#1#2 {\ifx#1\relax \else\ifnum\uccode`#1=`#1#1\fi\expandafter\abbreA\fi}

\def\macro{Modular and Response}

\abbre{Something Text is Here} or \abbre\macro.
```

Result is: STH or MR. The macro `\abbre` is expandable thus it can be edefed:

```
\edef\abbremacro{\abbre\marco} % Now the meaning of \abbremacro is MR.
```