# Biblatex display format of author name

Tags: biblatex

I am looking for a way to make biblatex to display the author names in format of First Middle Initial Last. I want biblatex to automatically convert from other formats of author names to the desired display format.

A MWE is like this:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{bib.bib}

@article{jdoe,
    author={Doe, John Paul},
    journal={Journal},
    title={Title},
    year=2014,
    pages={111--222},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\noindent Citation: \cite{jdoe}.
\printbibliography[]
\end{document}
```

I want to know how to add biblatex macros to make the display of the author names to be as John P. Doe, no matter what the format of the author names in .bib are specified. Is there an easy way to do so?

I have tried to use `\DeclareNameFormat{first-last}` in the preamble, but this did not work for me. Could you please help? Thanks.

Comment: It is not a proper MWE, it lacks the specification of which options are used for `biblatex` and it does not load `biblatex`. `\usepackage[<options>]{biblatex}` is missing.

Comment: Nor does it specify a bibliography or bibresource...

Comment: Do you think [Bibliography with BibLaTeX: Do not abbreviate first given (first) name and abbreviate all further given names](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/126061/35864) or [Have Biblatex display only the first of first names for an author](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/163514/35864) could help you (the first is probably pretty much exactly what you want, the second one is a related question)?