# Removing additional middle name with biblatex

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, apa-style

i'm using biblatex with apa style. I have some authors that have too many middle names. It give me something like this :

> Licht, C. M. M., de Geus, E. J. C., van Dyck, R., & Penninx, B. W. J. H. (2009). Association be- tween anxiety disorders and heart rate variability in The Netherlands Study of Depression and Anxiety (NESDA). Psychosomatic medicine, 71(5), 508–518

instead I would like to have something like this with a maximum of two middle name :

> Licht, C. M., de Geus, E. J., van Dyck, R., & Penninx, B. W. (2009). etc...

I can't find any nice way of doing that (without deleting the additional names from my bib entry). Hope you can help me.

This is the MWE :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{demo.bib}
@article{Licht2009,
abstract = {},
author = {Licht, Carmilla M M and de Geus, Eco J C and van Dyck, Richard and Penninx, Brenda W J H},
doi = {10.1097/PSY.0b013e3181a292a6},
issn = {1534-7796},
journal = {Psychosomatic medicine},
number = {5},
pages = {508--518},
pmid = {19414616},
title = {{Association between anxiety disorders and heart rate variability in The Netherlands Study of Depression and Anxiety (NESDA).}},
url = {http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/19414616},
volume = {71},
year = {2009}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa,citestyle=authoryear,natbib=true,uniquelist=minyear,doi=false]{biblatex}
\bibliography{demo}

\begin{document}
    A reference to : \cite{Licht2009}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Thanks.
br.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: You should cite the authors in the same way they are listed in the referenced document.

Comment: Thanks @egreg. But this is a rule i have to respect. Also, on [pubmed](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/19414616) they use only the first two letters of first names.

Comment: I agree with egreg that you should not do this. Maybe http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/126061/35864 and http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/163514/35864 can help you.

Comment: This will immediately break APA compliance of your document, I would have thought. Still, this can be achieved exactly as in [Have Biblatex display only the first of first names for an author](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/163514/35864).