# Make one author's name bold every time it shows up in the bibliography (continued)

Tags: bibliographies, formatting

The solution provided here

[Make one author's name bold every time it shows up in the bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33330/make-one-authors-name-bold-every-time-it-shows-up-in-the-bibliography/47655#47655)

does unfortunately not work, as soon as the Author's name contains
special characters, e.g. `Hans M{\"u}ller`?
How can this problem be solved?

Answer (score 4):

The following modification of [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/18668/4427) seems to work if you use the `plain` bib style:

```
\let\originalbibitem\bibitem
\def\bibitem#1#2\par{%
  \noexpandarg
  \originalbibitem{#1}
  \StrSubstitute{#2}{Hans M{\"u}ller}{\textbf{Hans M{\"u}ller}}\par}
```

Example

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{a,
author={M{\"u}ller, Gerd},
title={Scoring goals},
journal={J. Applied Soccer},
year={1974},
}
@article{b,
author={M{\"u}ller, Hans},
title={Splitting hairs},
journal={J. Abstract Tetrapiloctomy},
year={1255},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xstring}

\let\originalbibitem\bibitem
\def\bibitem#1#2\par{%
  \noexpandarg
  \originalbibitem{#1}
  \StrSubstitute{#2}{Hans M{\"u}ller}{\textbf{Hans M{\"u}ller}}\par}

\begin{document}
\cite{a}

\cite{b}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Well, the simple example indeed works, but
if I use a more complex example, e.g. with the web.sty and URLs,
I receive the error message(s): unaway argument?
...
! Paragraph ended before \BR@c@bibitem was complete.
<to be read again> \par

Comment: @PatrickJöckel This is not a forum, but a "question and answers" site. Please, edit the original question, rather than adding "non answers". You need to register, though. A moderator will merge the "different identities".

Comment: Thank you, @egreg! This is an excellent answer.

Comment: @egreg I'm hoping to use this method with the `\makebold` command (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/470783/use-value-from-xparse-key-value-store-in-regular-expressions#comment1186212_470785) instead of `StrSubstitute`. However, only the last bibliography entry works. Any suggestions?

Comment: @AdamErickson You probably are not separating a `\bibitem` from the next with a blank line.

Comment: @egreg I have it like this and it does not work unfortunately:
`\let\originalbibitem\bibitem
\def\bibitem#1#2\par{%
    \originalbibitem{#1}
    \makebold{#2}\par
}`

Comment: @egreg It appears to be the `\makebold` command that is causing this behaviour, as `\StrSubstitute` works as expected. Any ideas? I'd be happy to share my code.

Comment: @AdamErickson I'm not clairvoyant. If you have a question related to this one, but you're using a different set of macros, then ask it properly.

Comment: @egreg New question posted here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/471062/automatic-bold-formatting-of-author-name-in-bibliography

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a straightforward solution by modifying the `.bbl`-file with `sed`:

```
bibtex mydoc

mv my.bbl my.bbl.ori 

cat my.bbl.ori | tr '\n' '\t' | sed 's/\(M{\\\"u}ller, *\t* *H.\)/\\textbf{\1}/g'  | tr '\t' '\n' > my.bbl
```

The trick is to convert newlines to tabs in order to enable sed to wrap
the name into `\texbf{...}`, even if there is a newline in between.