# Underline my own name in the publication list created with bibentry

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, formatting, bibentry

I create my list of publications using `\bibentry`. As in some of the publications I'm only the fifth author (or there around) I would like to highlight my name by underlining it. I found solutions doing this in the complete bibliography e.g. [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18664/underline-my-name-in-the-bibliography) or [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33330/make-one-authors-name-bold-every-time-it-shows-up-in-the-bibliography). Is there a possibility to apply the underlining just locally for the "chapter" where I create the publication list using `\bibentry`? I'm also open to alternatives to `\bibentry` however I would prefer not to make the list completely by hand. I'm using BibTeX and the bibliographystyle [statto](http://www.jorrit.org/typo3/uploads/media/statto.bst).

Comment: Does `author={\underline{authorname}}` not work for you? Or probably I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: this works in the sense that the respective name is underlined in the bibliography and when I call them with `\bibentry`. However I would like to have the name only highlighted when calling the `\bibentry` for the publications list of *my* papers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make one author's name bold every time it shows up in the bibliography](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33330/make-one-authors-name-bold-every-time-it-shows-up-in-the-bibliography)

Comment: Have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33330/16895. The solutions can be trivially adapted to underlining instead of bold, and they should carry over `\bibentry` as well.

Comment: Yes, I have seen this question and the corresponding answer. However I'm looking for a solution where only the name in the entries in the publication list are underlined but *not* in the normal bibliography. Therefore I think this question treats a different aspect.

Comment: The question is different, but the solution is an extension of the solutions provided in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33330/make-one-authors-name-bold-every-time-it-shows-up-in-the-bibliography

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**  Answer updated with step-by-step instructions on how to modify the `.bst` file according to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/71476/16895).

It is possible to use the solution provided in this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/71476/16895) to [Make one author's name bold every time it shows up in the bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33330/make-one-authors-name-bold-every-time-it-shows-up-in-the-bibliography) as follows:

Create a command `\myref` that takes an argument, and use such command to wrap your name in the bibliography using the solutions above. This means that in the `.bbl` file one has something like

```
\bibitem[Author and M{\"u}ller(2013)]{A}
A~Author and \myref{M~M{\"}ller}.
\newblock Title, 2013.

\bibitem[M{\"u}ller(2013)]{B}
\myref{M~M{\"u}ller}.
\newblock Title, 2013.

\bibitem[Cuthor(2013)]{C}
C~Cuthor.
\newblock Title, 2013.
```

The command `\myref` is defined to simply print its content in a normal bibliography and print the underlined argument in the list of publication. This is achieved in the following way (using `toolbox` package `toggle` facilities)

```
\newtoggle{myrefs}

\newcommand{\myref}[1]{\iftoggle{myrefs}{\underline{#1}}{#1}}
```

then set `myrefs` to false before the normal bibliography (`\togglefalse{myrefs}`) and true for  the list of publications (`\toggletrue{myrefs}`).

Here is the complete example (the `\jobname.bbl` file is included to demonstrate the solution). Also the step-by-step modifications to the `.bst` file, according to [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/71476/16895) are included

Include the following functions in the `.bst` file (as usual create a copy  of the style and rename it).

```
FUNCTION {cv.author}
{ "M Muller" }

FUNCTION {highlight}
{ duplicate$ empty$
      { pop$ "" }
      { "\myref{" swap$ * "}" * }
   if$
}

FUNCTION {highlight.if.cv.author}
{ duplicate$ purify$ cv.author purify$ =
    { highlight }
    'skip$
  if$
}
```

Then locate the function `FUNCTION {format.names}` in the `.bst` file (it is around line 550 in my copy). Change

```
  format.name$
  bib.name.font
```

in

```
  format.name$
  highlight.if.cv.author
  bib.name.font
```

namely, add `highlight.if.cv.author` immediately after `format.name$`.

At this point you are ready to use the modified `.bst` file.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{bib.bib}
  @Misc{A,
    author       = {A Author and M M{\"u}ller},
    title        = {Title},
    year         = 2013,
  }

  @Misc{B,
    author       = {M M{\'}ller},
    title        = {Title},
    year         = 2013,
  }

  @Misc{C,
    author       = {C Cuthor},
    title        = {Title},
    year         = 2013,
  }
\end{filecontents}

\newtoggle{myrefs}

\newcommand{\myref}[1]{\iftoggle{myrefs}{\underline{#1}}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\togglefalse{myrefs}
\bibliographystyle{mystatto}
\bibliography{bib}

\section*{My Publications}
\toggletrue{myrefs}
\nobibliography*
\begin{itemize}
\item\bibentry{A}
\item\bibentry{B}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

The MWE yields

[image]

Comment: I guess this should work, at least when putting `\myname{Buthor, Bernd}` directly in the bib file it highlight correctly but will the not give the correct order of the names. So I guess, I should adapt the `statto.bst` somehow accordingly to this [solution](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33330/make-one-authors-name-bold-every-time-it-shows-up-in-the-bibliography). However I don't see where I have to make the corresponding adjustment. Could you help me here?

Comment: I tried to adapts it as following `     { "\FormatName{" s nameptr "{ff~}{vv~}{ll}{, jj}" format.name$ bib.name.font bibinfo bibinfo.check "}"  't :=
    %{ s nameptr "{ff~}{vv~}{ll}{, jj}" format.name$ bib.name.font bibinfo bibinfo.check 't :=` But this is not working (i.e. the names are now longer ordered by first name, last name and nothing is underlined). I don't know if a name as Müller (M\"uller) provides additional difficulty?

Comment: Try with the second answer (I have modified my  answer accordingly, with a link to this [answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/71476/16895). For names like Müller, use Muller instead.

Comment: Can you put it explicitly what and where I have to change it? I tried with names as Müller and names without Umlaut, I'm not getting it somehow. There is nothing highlighted at all.

Comment: I put the names in the wrong order, i.e. Burthor, Bernd instead of Bernd Buthor. The `\textbf` in the second solution I replaced by `\myref`and the everthing works fine. thanks

Comment: In the `.bib` file you can use either `Buthor, Bernd` or `Bernd Buthor`  in the string of the function in the modified `.bst` it must be `Bernd Bhutor`.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach to doing this is with [Bibulous](http://nzhagen.github.io/bibulous/) in place of BibTeX or Biblatex. In order make a given author underlined, all that is needed is to apply a "substring replace" operator into the author list variable. For example, to replace the author "J. W. Tukey" with its underlined version "\underline{J. W. Tukey}", we can change each entrytype template from, say,

```
article = <au>, \enquote{<title.replace(Sunset,\color{red}Sunset\color{black})>,}{ }...
          <journal.replace(American,\textit{American})> \textbf{<volume>} (<year>).
```

to the new form

```
article = <au.replace(J. W. Tukey,\underline{J. W. Tukey})>,{ }...
          \enquote{<title.replace(Sunset,\color{red}Sunset\color{black})>,}{ }...
          <journal.replace(American,\textit{American})> \textbf{<volume>} (<year>).
```

The change here is only applied to "article" type entries, and so similar changes to the other entrytype templates ("book", "inproceedings", etc.) would also be needed, in each case replacing `<au>` with `<au.replace(J. W. Tukey,\underline{J. W. Tukey})>`.