# Grouping mismatch if loop is dissolved

Tags: loops, grouping, ulem

I am sure that I overlooked something very obvious. Still, why does the example in [this nice answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/359320/47927) work, but if I remove the loop, I get an error about a grouping mismatch?

Consider the following minimal non-working example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{testref, 
  author = {Miller, Alice and Highlight, Shine and Smith, Bob},
  title = {The title},
  journal = {The journal},
  pages = {65--78},
  year = 2014}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}

\usepackage[backend=biber,bibencoding=utf8,style=numeric-comp,maxbibnames=99]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\newbox\savenamebox


% does not work
\newbibmacro*{name:bbold}[2]{%
  \iffieldequalstr{hash}{01b588ba4e4ad753feae6c81709fc04b}%
  {\bfseries\setbox\savenamebox\hbox\bgroup\listbreak}{}%
}

\newbibmacro*{name:ebold}[2]{%
  \iffieldequalstr{hash}{01b588ba4e4ad753feae6c81709fc04b}%
  {\egroup\uline{\usebox\savenamebox}\listbreak}{}%
}
% ===


\xpatchbibmacro{name:given-family}{\usebibmacro{name:delim}{#2#3#1}}{\usebibmacro{name:delim}{#2#3#1}\begingroup\usebibmacro{name:bbold}{#1}{#2}}{}{}

\xapptobibmacro{name:given-family}{\usebibmacro{name:ebold}{#1}{#2}\endgroup}{}{}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

The original code has instead

```
\newbibmacro*{name:bbold}[2]{%
  \def\do##1{\iffieldequalstr{hash}{##1}{\bfseries\setbox\savenamebox\hbox\bgroup\listbreak}{}}%
  \dolistloop{\boldnames}%
}

\newbibmacro*{name:ebold}[2]{%
  \def\do##1{\iffieldequalstr{hash}{##1}{\egroup\uline{\usebox\savenamebox}\listbreak}{}}%
  \dolistloop{\boldnames}%
}

\newcommand*{\boldnames}{}
\forcsvlist{\listadd\boldnames}{
  {4fcd4bca11ef811f3aef17c792b6ef3e},
  {01b588ba4e4ad753feae6c81709fc04b}}
```

This works well. But why is this? Does the loop somehow delay expansion so that the grouping mismatch is irrelevant? How could I get a working example without a loop?

Comment: You have `\listbreak` left-overs from the original code. Try without them.

Comment: @user691586 I see, so `\listbreak` is actually needed to go through the list generated by `\forcsvlist`, right? Then it makes a lot of sense that this macro should not be part of the macros without the loop! Thank you!

Comment: `latexdef -p etoolbox listbreak` returns `\listbreak:` `\long macro:#1&->` so it looks like a clean-up thing, I did not check the catcode of the  `&` though.  I guess it does what its name indicates, breaking out of a loop and for whatever reason that was needed in the original code you started with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem, as pointed out in the comments (thanks to [user691586](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/293669/user691586)), is that I forgot to  remove the `\listbreak` macros from the original code which are somehow used for processing the CSV list and which are not needed here any more. Without these, the code works fine:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{testref, 
  author = {Miller, Alice and Highlight, Shine and Smith, Bob},
  title = {The title},
  journal = {The journal},
  pages = {65--78},
  year = 2014}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}

\usepackage[backend=biber,bibencoding=utf8,style=numeric-comp,maxbibnames=99]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\newbox\savenamebox

\newbibmacro*{name:bbold}[2]{%
  \iffieldequalstr{hash}{01b588ba4e4ad753feae6c81709fc04b}%
  {\bfseries\setbox\savenamebox\hbox\bgroup}{}%
}

\newbibmacro*{name:ebold}[2]{%
  \iffieldequalstr{hash}{01b588ba4e4ad753feae6c81709fc04b}%
  {\egroup\uline{\usebox\savenamebox}}{}%
}

\xpatchbibmacro{name:given-family}{\usebibmacro{name:delim}{#2#3#1}}{\usebibmacro{name:delim}{#2#3#1}\begingroup\usebibmacro{name:bbold}{#1}{#2}}{}{}

\xapptobibmacro{name:given-family}{\usebibmacro{name:ebold}{#1}{#2}\endgroup}{}{}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]