# Use `\fullcite` instead of bibliography for publication list

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing

I need to create a list of my publications. This list should include a reference to the paper, the ranking of the venue and the paper's abstract. After the publication list, I want to include the papers.

**Problem:** My main issue is that I don't want to have a dedicated reference section but rather want to use my custom publication list. Obviously, when using `\fullcite`, citing the paper (in the text before the publication list) does not work fully (clicking the link just jumps to the first page).

Code (`main.tex`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{
 a4paper,
 total={170mm,257mm},
 left=20mm,
 top=20mm,
 }

\usepackage{enumitem}

 \usepackage[
backend=biber,
% style=alphabetic,
firstinits=true,
bibstyle=ieee,citestyle=numeric-comp,
maxnames=99,
% citestyle=authoryear
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/412872/85103 START

\def\makenamesetup{%
  \def\bibnamedelima{~}%
  \def\bibnamedelimb{ }%
  \def\bibnamedelimc{ }%
  \def\bibnamedelimd{ }%
  \def\bibnamedelimi{ }%
  \def\bibinitperiod{.}%
  \def\bibinitdelim{~}%
  \def\bibinithyphendelim{.-}}    
\newcommand*{\makename}[2]{\begingroup\makenamesetup\xdef#1{#2}\endgroup}

\newcommand*{\boldname}[3]{%
  \def\lastname{#1}%
  \def\firstname{#2}%
  \def\firstinit{#3}}
\boldname{}{}{}

\boldname{Lamport}{Leslie}{L.}

\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\namehighighter}[1]{%
  \ifboolexpr{(test {\ifdefequal{\firstname}{\namepartgiven}}
               or test {\ifdefequal{\firstinit}{\namepartgiven}})
              and test {\ifdefequal{\lastname}{\namepartfamily}}}
    {\uline{#1}}
    {#1}}

\renewbibmacro*{name:given-family}[4]{%
  \usebibmacro{name:delim}{#2#3#1}%
  \usebibmacro{name:hook}{#2#3#1}%
  \namehighighter{%
  \ifdefvoid{#2}{}{\mkbibnamegiven{#2}\isdot\bibnamedelimd}%
  \ifdefvoid{#3}{}{%
    \mkbibnameprefix{#3}\isdot
    \ifprefchar
      {}
      {\ifuseprefix{\bibnamedelimc}{\bibnamedelimd}}}%
  \mkbibnamefamily{#1}\isdot
  \ifdefvoid{#4}{}{\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnamesuffix{#4}\isdot}}}
\makeatother
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/412872/85103 END

\newcommand{\RNum}[1]{\uppercase\expandafter{\romannumeral #1\relax}}


% \pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\section*{\huge My Awesome Papers}

\subsection*{BLA 1}

I want to cite this paper~\cite{lamport2019part} and jump directly to the fullcite entry on the second page.

\subsection*{BLA 2}

\vspace{1em}

\noindent \emph{Time, clocks, and the ordering of events in a distributed system} \dotfill \hyperlink{page.1}{1}

\noindent \textbf{Reference:} \cite{lamport2019time} \fullcite{lamport2019time}

\noindent \textbf{Ranking:} A*

\noindent \textbf{Abstract:} 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In aliquam lacinia nulla quis convallis. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Mauris blandit, ligula vitae ornare tincidunt, mauris eros tincidunt diam, ac malesuada eros est ac turpis. In sed sollicitudin neque, eget malesuada leo. Phasellus gravida nisl ut mi dictum, sed pharetra metus fringilla. Ut laoreet suscipit consequat. Maecenas malesuada ex magna, quis hendrerit diam finibus eu. Nullam consectetur nunc sed rutrum consequat. Donec nulla leo, convallis et sagittis in, rhoncus eget arcu.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In aliquam lacinia nulla quis convallis. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Mauris blandit, ligula vitae ornare tincidunt, mauris eros tincidunt diam, ac malesuada eros est ac turpis. In sed sollicitudin neque, eget malesuada leo. Phasellus gravida nisl ut mi dictum, sed pharetra metus fringilla. Ut laoreet suscipit consequat. Maecenas malesuada ex magna, quis hendrerit diam finibus eu. Nullam consectetur nunc sed rutrum consequat. Donec nulla leo, convallis et sagittis in, rhoncus eget arcu.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In aliquam lacinia nulla quis convallis. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Mauris blandit, ligula vitae ornare tincidunt, mauris eros tincidunt diam, ac malesuada eros est ac turpis. In sed sollicitudin neque, eget malesuada leo. Phasellus gravida nisl ut mi dictum, sed pharetra metus fringilla. Ut laoreet suscipit consequat. Maecenas malesuada ex magna, quis hendrerit diam finibus eu. Nullam consectetur nunc sed rutrum consequat. Donec nulla leo, convallis et sagittis in, rhoncus eget arcu.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In aliquam lacinia nulla quis convallis. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Mauris blandit, ligula vitae ornare tincidunt, mauris eros tincidunt diam, ac malesuada eros est ac turpis. In sed sollicitudin neque, eget malesuada leo. Phasellus gravida nisl ut mi dictum, sed pharetra metus fringilla. Ut laoreet suscipit consequat. Maecenas malesuada ex magna, quis hendrerit diam finibus eu. Nullam consectetur nunc sed rutrum consequat. Donec nulla leo, convallis et sagittis in, rhoncus eget arcu.

\vspace{2em}

\noindent \emph{The Byzantine generals problem} \dotfill \hyperlink{page.1}{1}

\noindent \textbf{Reference:} \cite{lamport2019byzantine} \fullcite{lamport2019byzantine}

\noindent \textbf{Ranking:} A*

\noindent \textbf{Abstract:} 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In aliquam lacinia nulla quis convallis. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Mauris blandit, ligula vitae ornare tincidunt, mauris eros tincidunt diam, ac malesuada eros est ac turpis. In sed sollicitudin neque, eget malesuada leo. Phasellus gravida nisl ut mi dictum, sed pharetra metus fringilla. Ut laoreet suscipit consequat. Maecenas malesuada ex magna, quis hendrerit diam finibus eu. Nullam consectetur nunc sed rutrum consequat. Donec nulla leo, convallis et sagittis in, rhoncus eget arcu.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In aliquam lacinia nulla quis convallis. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Mauris blandit, ligula vitae ornare tincidunt, mauris eros tincidunt diam, ac malesuada eros est ac turpis. In sed sollicitudin neque, eget malesuada leo. Phasellus gravida nisl ut mi dictum, sed pharetra metus fringilla. Ut laoreet suscipit consequat. Maecenas malesuada ex magna, quis hendrerit diam finibus eu. Nullam consectetur nunc sed rutrum consequat. Donec nulla leo, convallis et sagittis in, rhoncus eget arcu.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In aliquam lacinia nulla quis convallis. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Mauris blandit, ligula vitae ornare tincidunt, mauris eros tincidunt diam, ac malesuada eros est ac turpis. In sed sollicitudin neque, eget malesuada leo. Phasellus gravida nisl ut mi dictum, sed pharetra metus fringilla. Ut laoreet suscipit consequat. Maecenas malesuada ex magna, quis hendrerit diam finibus eu. Nullam consectetur nunc sed rutrum consequat. Donec nulla leo, convallis et sagittis in, rhoncus eget arcu.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In aliquam lacinia nulla quis convallis. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Mauris blandit, ligula vitae ornare tincidunt, mauris eros tincidunt diam, ac malesuada eros est ac turpis. In sed sollicitudin neque, eget malesuada leo. Phasellus gravida nisl ut mi dictum, sed pharetra metus fringilla. Ut laoreet suscipit consequat. Maecenas malesuada ex magna, quis hendrerit diam finibus eu. Nullam consectetur nunc sed rutrum consequat. Donec nulla leo, convallis et sagittis in, rhoncus eget arcu.

\vspace{2em}

\noindent \emph{The part-time parliament} \dotfill \hyperlink{page.1}{1}

\noindent \textbf{Reference:} \cite{lamport2019part} \fullcite{lamport2019part}

\noindent \textbf{Ranking:} A*

\noindent \textbf{Abstract:} 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In aliquam lacinia nulla quis convallis. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Mauris blandit, ligula vitae ornare tincidunt, mauris eros tincidunt diam, ac malesuada eros est ac turpis. In sed sollicitudin neque, eget malesuada leo. Phasellus gravida nisl ut mi dictum, sed pharetra metus fringilla. Ut laoreet suscipit consequat. Maecenas malesuada ex magna, quis hendrerit diam finibus eu. Nullam consectetur nunc sed rutrum consequat. Donec nulla leo, convallis et sagittis in, rhoncus eget arcu.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In aliquam lacinia nulla quis convallis. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Mauris blandit, ligula vitae ornare tincidunt, mauris eros tincidunt diam, ac malesuada eros est ac turpis. In sed sollicitudin neque, eget malesuada leo. Phasellus gravida nisl ut mi dictum, sed pharetra metus fringilla. Ut laoreet suscipit consequat. Maecenas malesuada ex magna, quis hendrerit diam finibus eu. Nullam consectetur nunc sed rutrum consequat. Donec nulla leo, convallis et sagittis in, rhoncus eget arcu.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In aliquam lacinia nulla quis convallis. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Mauris blandit, ligula vitae ornare tincidunt, mauris eros tincidunt diam, ac malesuada eros est ac turpis. In sed sollicitudin neque, eget malesuada leo. Phasellus gravida nisl ut mi dictum, sed pharetra metus fringilla. Ut laoreet suscipit consequat. Maecenas malesuada ex magna, quis hendrerit diam finibus eu. Nullam consectetur nunc sed rutrum consequat. Donec nulla leo, convallis et sagittis in, rhoncus eget arcu.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In aliquam lacinia nulla quis convallis. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Mauris blandit, ligula vitae ornare tincidunt, mauris eros tincidunt diam, ac malesuada eros est ac turpis. In sed sollicitudin neque, eget malesuada leo. Phasellus gravida nisl ut mi dictum, sed pharetra metus fringilla. Ut laoreet suscipit consequat. Maecenas malesuada ex magna, quis hendrerit diam finibus eu. Nullam consectetur nunc sed rutrum consequat. Donec nulla leo, convallis et sagittis in, rhoncus eget arcu.

\vspace{2em}


% \includepdf[pages=-]{./papers/A.pdf}

% \includepdf[pages=-]{./papers/B.pdf}

% \includepdf[pages=-]{./papers/C.pdf}

\end{document}
```

Bib (`bibliography.bib`):

```
@incollection{lamport2019time,
  title={Time, clocks, and the ordering of events in a distributed system},
  author={Lamport, Leslie},
  booktitle={Concurrency: the Works of Leslie Lamport},
  pages={179--196},
  year={2019}
}

@incollection{lamport2019byzantine,
  title={The Byzantine generals problem},
  author={Lamport, Leslie and Shostak, Robert and Pease, Marshall},
  booktitle={Concurrency: the works of leslie lamport},
  pages={203--226},
  year={2019}
}

@incollection{lamport2019part,
  title={The part-time parliament},
  author={Lamport, Leslie},
  booktitle={Concurrency: the Works of Leslie Lamport},
  pages={277--317},
  year={2019}
}
```

Again, to clarify my problem: When I use, for instance, `\cite{lamport2019part}`, the ref does not jump to the respective `\fullcite` entry. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add the target. But naturally you should only use \fullcite once for every entry.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
firstinits=true,
bibstyle=ieee,citestyle=numeric-comp,
maxnames=99,
]{biblatex}

\makeatletter
\DeclareCiteCommand{\fullcite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\MakeLinkTarget*{cite.\the\c@refsection @\thefield{entrykey}}{}% add target
   \usedriver
     {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
     {\thefield{entrytype}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
\addbibresource{hyp.bib}
\makeatother
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}


I want to cite this paper~\cite{lamport2019part} and jump directly to the fullcite entry on the second page.

\newpage 

\fullcite{lamport2019part}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you Ulrike. You are doing an amazing job! I really appreciate your help. Exactly like I wanted it to be.