# Hierarchy of inheritance in bibtex crossrefs - not inheriting second layer

Tags: bibtex, cross-referencing

I have entries in my bibtex file as follows:

```
@inproceedings{Kang2011,
    author = {Kang, Hongwen and Hebert, Martial and Kanade, Takeo},
    title = {{Discovering object instances from scenes of Daily Living}},
    crossref = {iccv-2011},
    pages = {762--769}
}

@proceedings{iccv-2011,
    crossref = {iccv},
    year = {2011} }

@misc{iccv,
    booktitle = {International Conference on Computer Vision (ICCV)}
}
```

The idea is that if I wish to change how a conference name is written, I need only do it in one place - this is inspired by [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/4460/3588).

However, when compiling a latex document using this, the year from the `@proceedings` shows up in the bibliography, but not the conference name from `@misc`:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe you need to bibtex it twice to get all the references connected?

Comment: If this kind of thing is important to you, perhaps [CrossTeX](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/people/egs/crosstex/index.php) will appeal to you.  I don't think it is still actively developed, but it supports the four basic BibTeX styles.  (Or so says the website; I'm happy with `biblatex`, so I never really used `CrossTeX`.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of using nested crossrefs, you can create strings, and use them instead on the innermost crossref. This should be compatible with the use in your example.

```
@inproceedings{Kang2011,
    author = {Kang, Hongwen and Hebert, Martial and Kanade, Takeo},
    title = {{Discovering object instances from scenes of Daily Living}},
    crossref = {iccv-2011},
    pages = {762--769}
}

@proceedings{iccv-2011,
    booktitle = iccv,
    year = {2011} }

@string{iccv = {International Conference on Computer Vision (ICCV)}}
```

Comment: This is how I deal with short and full journal titles - one file with strings defining all the abbreviated titles, and one with the same keys defining strings for the full names. Include one or the other to switch from short to long names. This way you never actually change anything in your .bib files, you only have one change to make in your .tex file to switch all the names.

Answer (score 5):

It can't be done. From the [bibtex](http://mirrors.ctan.org/biblio/bibtex/base/btxdoc.pdf) manual, page 3:

> (Moreover, you may not reliably nest cross references; that is, a cross-
>   referenced entry may not itself reliably cross reference an entry. This is
>   almost certainly not something you’d want to do, though.)

Answer (score 0):

Just a demonstration that switching to Biblatex solves the problem:

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@inproceedings{Kang2011,
    author = {Kang, Hongwen and Hebert, Martial and Kanade, Takeo},
    title = {{Discovering object instances from scenes of Daily Living}},
    crossref = {iccv-2011},
    pages = {762--769}
}

@proceedings{iccv-2011,
    crossref = {iccv},
    year = {2011} }

@misc{iccv,
    booktitle = {International Conference on Computer Vision (ICCV)}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\begin{document}

  \cite{Kang2011}
  \printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image: nested cross references with Biblatex]