# Consolidate BibTeX crossrefs into new .bib file

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, jabref

I have three BibTeX files set up:

- `main.bib`, which contains all the main reference entries for papers. These use `crossref` to reference entries in...
- `crossrefs.bib` which contains all the details of conferences and journals. This draws upon...
- `strings.bib`, which contains string definitions of things like conference names.

This works fine when compiling latex documents. However, I wish to convert all my citations into `xml` format to be imported into MS Word – this is causing me some troubles.

The method I have used to convert my `bib` files to `xml` is:

- Import all `.bib` files into JabRef
- Export as `xml` format

However, the crossrefs remain as crossrefs in the exported file. When used in MS Word, therefore, only the title and author of each paper is visible in each citation.

I would like all the entries to be consolidated, such that each entry in my main file contains all the details from  `crossrefs.bib` and `strings.bib`.

Is there a script (or JabRef option/alternative) which will perform this consolidation of crossrefs and strings?

---

**EDIT**

The BibTeX files are set up as in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/98150/3588).

In JabRef the entries look like this:

[image]

The crossrefs haven't been populated but I believe JabRef does understand cross-referencing.

An example entry from the `xml` output is as follows:

```
<b:Source>
<b:SourceType>ConferenceProceedings</b:SourceType>
<b:BIBTEX_Entry>inproceedings</b:BIBTEX_Entry>
<b:Tag>jia-cvpr-2013</b:Tag>
<b:Title>{3D}-Based Reasoning with Blocks, Support, and Stability</b:Title>
<b:Author>
<b:Author>
<b:NameList>
<b:Person>
<b:Last>Chen</b:Last>
<b:First>Tsuhan</b:First>
</b:Person>

...snip...

</b:NameList>
</b:Author>
</b:Author>
<b:BIBTEX_CrossRef>cvpr-2013</b:BIBTEX_CrossRef>
</b:Source>
```

As you can see, the crossref remains, and Word cannot resolve this. It appears in the bibliography as so:

[image]

(The braces {} also remain, but this is less of an issue...)

I imagine a solution to this problem would also help people who have begun their BibTeX files with crossrefs but now want to revert to a non-crossref solution!

Comment: I know :). I have provided some explanation of what my files look like. The answer which has been linked below the **EDIT** line shows how the crossreferencing has been set up.

Comment: You can probably do it with `biber`.

Comment: `bibtool` has capabilities along these lines, expanding strings which it calls `macros` and extracting data from `cross-refs`.  See the documentation on https://www.ctan.org/pkg/bibtool?lang=en